# Can't specify the 'async' modifier on the 'Main' method of a console app

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, console-application

I am new to asynchronous programming with the `async` modifier. I am trying to figure out how to make sure that my `Main` method of a console application actually runs asynchronously.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bootstrapper bs = new Bootstrapper();
        var list = bs.GetList();
    }
}

public class Bootstrapper {

    public async Task<List<TvChannel>> GetList()
    {
        GetPrograms pro = new GetPrograms();

        return await pro.DownloadTvChannels();
    }
}
```

I know this is not running asynchronously from "the top." Since it is not possible to specify the `async` modifier on the `Main` method, how can I run code within `main` asynchronously?

Comment: This is no longer the case in C#7.1. Main methods can be async

Comment: Here's the [C#7.1 blog post announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/31/welcome-to-c-7-1/#gist82557368). See the section titled **Async Main**.

Answer (score 551, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2012, the compiler would disallow an `async Main` method. This was allowed (but never recommended) in Visual Studio 2010 with the Async CTP.

As of Visual Studio 2017 Update 3 (15.3), the language now supports an `async Main` - as long as it returns `Task` or `Task<T>`. So you can now do this:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bootstrapper bs = new Bootstrapper();
        var list = await bs.GetList();
    }
}
```

The semantics appear to be the same as the `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` style of blocking the main thread. However, there's no language spec for C# 7.1 yet, so this is only an assumption.

---

I have blog posts about [async/await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [asynchronous console programs](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html) in particular. Here's some background info from the intro post:

> If "await" sees that the awaitable has not completed, then it acts asynchronously. It tells the awaitable to run the remainder of the method when it completes, and then *returns* from the async method. Await will also capture the current **context** when it passes the remainder of the method to the awaitable.
>
> Later on, when the awaitable completes, it will execute the remainder of the async method (within the captured context).

Here's why this is a problem in Console programs with an `async Main`:

> Remember from our intro post that an async method will *return* to its caller before it is complete. This works perfectly in UI applications (the method just returns to the UI event loop) and ASP.NET applications (the method returns off the thread but keeps the request alive). It doesn't work out so well for Console programs: Main returns to the OS - so your program exits.

One solution is to provide your own context - a "main loop" for your console program that is async-compatible.

If you have a machine with the Async CTP, you can use `GeneralThreadAffineContext` from *My Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP\Samples(C# Testing) Unit Testing\AsyncTestUtilities*. Alternatively, you can use [`AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) from [my Nito.AsyncEx NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx).

Here's an example using `AsyncContext`; `GeneralThreadAffineContext` has almost identical usage:

```
using Nito.AsyncEx;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsyncContext.Run(() => MainAsync(args));
    }

    static async void MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        Bootstrapper bs = new Bootstrapper();
        var list = await bs.GetList();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can just block the main Console thread until your asynchronous work has completed:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        Bootstrapper bs = new Bootstrapper();
        var list = await bs.GetList();
    }
}
```

Note the use of `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`; this avoids the `AggregateException` wrapping that happens if you use `Wait()` or `Result`.

Comment: You *can* use a simple `Wait` or `Result`, and there's nothing wrong with that. But be aware that there are two important differences: 1) all `async` continuations run on the thread pool rather than the main thread, and 2) any exceptions are wrapped in an `AggregateException`.

Comment: Was having a real problem figuring this out until this (and your blog post). This is by far the easiest method to solve this problem, and you can install the package in the nuget console with just a "install-package Nito.Asyncex" and you are done.

Comment: My problem with these solutions is that the debugger (Visual Studio 2017 15.3.1) breaks in the Main method, not on the location where the Exception is thrown, and the Call Stack window is empty.

Comment: @Greg: If you want to break when the exception is thrown, then select "Break when Thrown" for the appropriate category in the Exception Settings window.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Thanks for the fast response Stephen.  I don't understand why anyone *wouldn't* want the debugger to break when an exception is thrown.  If I'm debugging and run across a null reference exception, going directly to the offending line of code seems preferred.   VS works like that "out of the box" for synchronous code, but not for async/await.

Comment: C# 7.1 has a async main now, might be worth adding to your great answer, @StephenCleary https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main.md

Comment: @greg This is probably because [some libraries use exceptions for control flow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189222/83653), in which case you don’t want to break for exceptions because there will be a lot and they will all be “expected” or part of normal operation. VS does mostly address this issue with the Just My Code feature, though.

Comment: If your using the C# 7.1 version in VS 2017 I needed to ensure the project was configured to use the latest version of the language by adding `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` into the csproj file, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45958948/542251).

Comment: Unfortunately, a similar update to allow `Async Main` has not been provided for VB.

Comment: However, it's not possible to select async main in project options/Application/Startup object.

Comment: As of January 2021 this feature is marked as a "proposal". It has been almost 3 years since it was documented on the Microsoft page that describes it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main

Comment: This feature appears to be a misnomer because it is called "async Main" . The adjective does not apply because it's really a "Task Main" declaration. The feature is documented wrong where it says... "Allow await to be used in an application's Main / entrypoint method". If you try to use "await" you will get the CS4032 error that await can only be used within an async method. The document is silent on how the command line is supposed to receive Task and Task<int> which is a bizarre oversight. The least they could do is to write "invoke it the same as you would "void Main".

Comment: This feature is misnamed and wrongly described and incompletely described. I am angry because it wouldn't take much to have avoided these shortcomings. Reading Microsoft documents is to strike a balance between acceptance and skepticism and to continually adjust.

Comment: @H2ONaCl: I believe all the MS docs are open-source now, and they take pull requests.

Comment: *`static async void MainAsync(string[] args)`* -- Is the `async void` intentional or a typo? I expected to see `async Task`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Either one works. It I was writing this answer today, I'd use `async Task`.

Answer (score 393):

You can solve this with this simple construct:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            // Do any async anything you need here without worry
        }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

That will put everything you do out on the ThreadPool where you'd want it (so other Tasks you start/await don't attempt to rejoin a Thread they shouldn't), and wait until everything's done before closing the Console app. No need for special loops or outside libs.

Edit: Incorporate Andrew's solution for uncaught Exceptions.

Comment: This approach is very obvious but tends to wrap exceptions so I'm looking now for a better way.

Comment: @abatishchev You should be using try/catch in your code, at least inside the Task.Run if not more granularly, not letting exceptions float up to the Task. You'll avoid the wrap up problem by putting try/catch around things that can fail.

Comment: If you replace `Wait()` with `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` you'll avoid the `AggregateException` wrapper when things throw.

Comment: This is how `async main` is being introduced in C# 7.1, as of this writing.

Comment: @user9993 According to [this proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main.md), that's not exactly true.

Answer (score 93):

You can do this without needing external libraries also by doing the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bootstrapper bs = new Bootstrapper();
        var getListTask = bs.GetList(); // returns the Task<List<TvChannel>>

        Task.WaitAll(getListTask); // block while the task completes

        var list = getListTask.Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `getListTask.Result` is also a blocking call and so the above code could be written without `Task.WaitAll(getListTask)`.

Comment: Also, if `GetList` throws you will have to catch an `AggregateException` and interrogate its exceptions to determine the actual exception thrown. You can, however, call `GetAwaiter()` to get the `TaskAwaiter` for the `Task`, and call `GetResult()` on that, ie `var list = getListTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();`. When getting the result from the `TaskAwaiter` (also a blocking call) any exceptions thrown will not be wrapped in an `AggregateException`.

Comment: .GetAwaiter().GetResult was the answer I needed. That works perfectly for what I was attempting to do. I will probably use this in other places as well.

Answer (score 92):

In C# 7.1 you will be able to do a proper *async Main*. The appropriate signatures for `Main` method has been extended to:

```
public static Task Main();
public static Task<int> Main();
public static Task Main(string[] args);
public static Task<int> Main(string[] args);
```

For e.g. you could be doing:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Bootstrapper bs = new Bootstrapper();
    var list = await bs.GetList();
}
```

At compile time, the async entry point method will be translated to call `GetAwaitor().GetResult()`.

Details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main

EDIT:

To enable C# 7.1 language features, you need to right-click on the project and click "Properties" then go to the "Build" tab. There, click the advanced button at the bottom:

[image]

From the language version drop-down menu, select "7.1" (or any higher value):

[image]

The default is "latest major version" which would evaluate (at the time of this writing) to C# 7.0, which does not support async main in console apps.

Comment: FWIW this is available in Visual Studio 15.3 and up, which is currently available as a beta/preview release from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/

Comment: Wait a minute... I'm running a fully updated install and my latest option is 7.1... how'd you get 7.2 already in May?

Comment: May answer was mine. October edit was by someone else by the time I think 7.2 (preview?) might have got released.

Comment: For an example have a look at this GitHub repo: https://github.com/nicknijenhuis/ChromeCastBackgroundSyncer

Comment: Heads up - check that it is on all configs, not just debug when you do this!

Answer (score 83):

I'll add an important feature that all of the other answers have overlooked: cancellation.

One of the big things in TPL is cancellation support, and console apps have a method of cancellation built in (CTRL+C). It's very simple to bind them together. This is how I structure all of my async console apps:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    
    System.Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        cts.Cancel();
    };

    MainAsync(args, cts.Token).GetAwaiter.GetResult();
}

static async Task MainAsync(string[] args, CancellationToken token)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Should the cancellation token be passed to the `Wait()` as well?

Comment: No, because you want the async code a be able to gracefully handle the cancellation. If you pass it to the `Wait()`, it won't wait for the async code to finish -- it'll stop waiting and end the process immediately.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I've just tried it out, and it seems like the cancellation request is being processed at the deepest level, even when the `Wait()` method is passed the same token.
What I'm trying to say is, that it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I'm sure. You want to cancel the op itself, not the wait for the op to finish. Unless you don't care about cleanup code finishing or the result of it.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get it, it just didn't seem to make any difference in my code. Another thing that threw me off course was a polite ReSharper hint about the wait method supporting cancellation ;) You might want to include a try catch in the example, as it will throw an OperationCancelledException, which I couldn't figure out at first

Comment: @Siewers In your code, you’re probably synchronously handling the cancellation somehow. There are situations where a token will be cancelled but you will still wait for some task to complete prior to throwing `OperationCanceledException`. If you did that, you should notice a difference in behavior because passing the token to `Wait()` would cause it to abort prior to your program’s `Task` completing.

Answer (score 29):

C# 7.1 (using vs 2017 update 3) introduces `async Main`:

You can write:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await ...
}
```

For more details [C# 7 Series, Part 2: Async Main](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/)

**Update:**

You may get a compilation error:

> Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

This error is due to that vs2017.3 is configured by default as c#7.0 not c#7.1.

You should  explicitly modify  the setting of your project to set c#7.1 features.

You can set c#7.1  by two methods:

**Method 1: Using the project settings window:**

- Open the settings of your project
- Select the Build tab
- Click the Advanced button
- Select the version you want
  As shown in the following figure:

[image]

**Method2: Modify PropertyGroup of .csproj manually**

Add this property:

```xml
<LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
```

example:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 22):

If you're using C# 7.1 or later, go with the [nawfal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44254451/704144) and just change the return type of your Main method to `Task` or `Task<int>`. If you are not:

- Have an `async Task MainAsync` [like Johan said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25631938/704144).
- Call its `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to catch the underlying exception [like do0g said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app#comment38322249_17579418).
- Support cancellation [like Cory said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25632189/704144).
- A second `CTRL+C` should terminate the process immediately. (Thanks [binki](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9208921#comment85111086_39350144)!)
- Handle `OperationCancelledException` - return an appropriate error code.

The final code looks like:

```
private static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
    {
        e.Cancel = !cts.IsCancellationRequested;
        cts.Cancel();
    };

    try
    {
        return MainAsync(args, cts.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        return 1223; // Cancelled.
    }
}

private static async Task<int> MainAsync(string[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Your code...

    return await Task.FromResult(0); // Success.
}
```

Comment: Many nice programs will cancel the CancelKeyPress only the first time so that if you press ^C once you get a graceful shutdown but if you’re impatient a second ^C terminates ungracefully. With this solution, you’d need to manually kill the program if it fails to honor the CancellationToken because `e.Cancel = true` is unconditional.

Answer (score 18):

Haven't needed this much yet, but when I've used console application for Quick tests and required async I've just solved it like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync(args).Wait();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This example will work wrong in case when you have to schedule task to current context and then wait it (for example, you can forget to add ConfigureAwait(false), so return method will be scheduled into the main thread, which is in Wait function). Because the current thread is in wait state, you will receive a deadlock.

Comment: Not true, @ManushinIgor. At least in this trivial example, there is no `SynchronizationContext` associated with the main thread. So it won't deadlock because even without `ConfigureAwait(false)`, all continuations will execute on the threadpool.

Answer (score 5):

For asynchronously calling task from Main, use

1. Task.Run() for .NET 4.5
2. Task.Factory.StartNew() for .NET 4.0   (May require Microsoft.Bcl.Async library for async and await keywords)

Details:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Newest version of C# - C# 7.1 allows to create async console app. To enable C# 7.1 in project, you have to upgrade your VS to at least 15.3, and change C# version to `C# 7.1` or `C# latest minor version`. To do this, go to Project properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Language version.

After this, following code will work:

```
internal class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
         (...)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

As of C# 7.1 the following signatures are valid for the [`Main`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#overview) method.

```
public static void Main() { }
public static int Main() { }
public static void Main(string[] args) { }
public static int Main(string[] args) { }
public static async Task Main() { }
public static async Task<int> Main() { }
public static async Task Main(string[] args) { }
public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args) { }
```

So, now you can do async/await

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello Asyn Main method!");
    await Task.Delay(200);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When the C# 5 CTP was introduced, you certainly *could* mark Main with `async`... although it was generally not a good idea to do so. I believe this was changed by the release of VS 2013 to become an error.

Unless you've started any other *foreground* threads, your program will exit when `Main` completes, even if it's started some background work.

What are you *really* trying to do? Note that your `GetList()` method really doesn't need to be async at the moment - it's adding an extra layer for no real reason. It's logically equivalent to (but more complicated than):

```
public Task<List<TvChannel>> GetList()
{
    return new GetPrograms().DownloadTvChannels();
}
```

Comment: Jon, I want to get the items in the list asynchronously, so why is the async not appropriate on that GetList method ? Is it because I need to collect the items in the list async' and not the list itself ?

When I try to mark the Main method with async I get a "does not contain a static Main method..."

Comment: @danielovich: What does `DownloadTvChannels()` return? Presumably it returns a `Task<List<TvChannel>>` doesn't it? If not, it's unlikely that you'd be able to await it. (Possible, given the awaiter pattern, but unlikely.) As for the `Main` method - it still needs to be static... did you *replace* the `static` modifier with the `async` modifier perhaps?

Comment: yes, it returns a Task<..> like you said. No matter how I try to put async in the Main method signature it throws an error. I am sitting on VS11 preview bits!

Comment: @danielovich: Even with a void return type? Just `public static async void Main() {}`? But if `DownloadTvChannels()` already returns a `Task<List<TvChannel>>`, presumably it's already asynchronous - so you don't need to add another layer. It's worth understanding this carefully.

Comment: yes, it's not working no matter what! That was why I tried to do another abstraction on top...

Comment: @danielovich: Okay, I'll try with the VS11 Preview at home tonight, but it definitely worked with the CTP. But as I say, you usually don't want to do that anyway - and you *don't* need your method to be an async method. It's not clear you really need your method anyway. What are you trying to achieve with your console app? Currently it will start fetching the TV channels but then terminate immediately, which is presumably not really what you want.

Comment: @danielovich: Yes, it's worth diving into it in detail rather than using it just from examples. You may want to read my blog posts on it (http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/async/default.aspx) as well as those by Eric Lippert, Mads Torgersen, Stephen Toub etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I'd be curious to hear more about the foreground thread approach.

Comment: @JonSkeet "it's adding an extra layer for no real reason" Is there any reason to use async/await throughout a console application, if I use ````Task.Wait()```` in ````Main```` anyway? E. g., if you use an async-only library like ````HttpClient````, should you make all calling methods async, too, and use ````Task.Wait()```` in ````Main```` or should you directly use ````Task.Wait()```` in the first method invoking a method of ````HttpClient````?

Comment: @NiklasPeter: If you're working with naturally-async APIs, it's typically cleaner to write your code in terms of async as well, and have one "switching" point where you wait for the result, rather than calling `Wait()` or `Result` all over the place. (Blocking for a task's completion is also dangerous in certain contexts, due to re-entrancy - so you want to do it in as few places as possible, and think about them carefully.)

Comment: If you mark Main method with async keyword I reckon it wont compile? What do you mean by your first line Jon?

Comment: @nawfal: When I wrote the answer, that compiled. I believe C# 6 changed that... it's possible that C# 7 will change it back again.

Comment: @nawfal: Looking back, I think it changed before VS2013 was released. Not sure if C# 7 will be changing that...

Answer (score 2):

In Main try changing the call to GetList to:

```
Task.Run(() => bs.GetList());
```

Answer (score 2):

On MSDN, the documentation for [Task.Run Method (Action)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides this example which shows how to run a method asynchronously from `main`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ShowThreadInfo("Application");

        var t = Task.Run(() => ShowThreadInfo("Task") );
        t.Wait();
    }

    static void ShowThreadInfo(String s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Thread ID: {1}",
                          s, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       Application thread ID: 1
//       Task thread ID: 3
```

Note this statement that follows the example:

> The examples show that the asynchronous task executes on a different
>   thread than the main application thread.

So, if instead you want the task to run on the main application thread, see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212343/1497596) by [@StephenCleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary).

And regarding the thread on which the task runs, also note Stephen's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/async-on-main-method-of-console-app#comment36626508_9212343) on his answer:

> You *can* use a simple `Wait` or `Result`, and there's nothing wrong
>   with that. But be aware that there are two important differences: 1)
>   all `async` continuations run on the thread pool rather than the main
>   thread, and 2) any exceptions are wrapped in an `AggregateException`.

(See [Exception Handling (Task Parallel Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for how to incorporate exception handling to deal with an `AggregateException`.)

---

Finally, on MSDN from the documentation for [Task.Delay Method (TimeSpan)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139096%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this example shows how to run an asynchronous task that returns a value:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var t = Task.Run(async delegate
                {
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
                    return 42;
                });
        t.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Task t Status: {0}, Result: {1}",
                          t.Status, t.Result);
    }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//        Task t Status: RanToCompletion, Result: 42
```

Note that instead of passing a `delegate` to `Task.Run`, you can instead pass a lambda function like this:

```cs
var t = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
            return 42;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a list of jobs that I wanted to run in async from my main method, have been using this in production for quite sometime and works fine.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(async () => { await Task.WhenAll(jobslist.Select(nl => RunMulti(nl))); }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
private static async Task RunMulti(List<string> joblist)
{
    await ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid freezing when you call a function somewhere down the call stack that tries to re-join the current thread (which is stuck in a Wait), you need to do the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bootstrapper bs = new Bootstrapper();
        List<TvChannel> list = Task.Run((Func<Task<List<TvChannel>>>)bs.GetList).Result;
    }
}
```

(the cast is only required to resolve ambiguity)

Comment: Thanks; Task.Run doesn't cause the deadlock of GetList().Wait, this answer shold have more upvotes...

Answer (score -2):

```
class Program
{
     public static EventHandler AsyncHandler;
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        AsyncHandler+= async (sender, eventArgs) => { await AsyncMain(); };
        AsyncHandler?.Invoke(null, null);
     }

     private async Task AsyncMain()
     {
        //Your Async Code
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Depending on whether you have to use async/await at the top level, you could create a new thread instead:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var context = new Thread(() => /*do stuff*/);
    context.Start();
    context.Join();
}
```

On the other hand, this also works:

```
Task.Run(async () => await /*Do Stuff*/).Wait();
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I wanted to await a method on load.  I ended up using the Main_Shown handler and making it async:

```
private async void Main_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await myAsyncMethod();
}
```