# An entry point cannot be marked with the 'async' modifier

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I copied below code from [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2012/06/26/understanding-a-simple-async-program.aspx)  link.But when I am compiling this code I am getting  an **entry point cannot be marked with the 'async' modifier**. How can I make this code compilable?

```
class Program
{
    static async void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<string> getWebPageTask = GetWebPageAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

        Debug.WriteLine("In startButton_Click before await");
        string webText = await getWebPageTask;
        Debug.WriteLine("Characters received: " + webText.Length.ToString()); 
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetWebPageAsync(string url)
    {
        // Start an async task. 
        Task<string> getStringTask = (new HttpClient()).GetStringAsync(url);

        // Await the task. This is what happens: 
        // 1. Execution immediately returns to the calling method, returning a 
        //    different task from the task created in the previous statement. 
        //    Execution in this method is suspended. 
        // 2. When the task created in the previous statement completes, the 
        //    result from the GetStringAsync method is produced by the Await 
        //    statement, and execution continues within this method. 
        Debug.WriteLine("In GetWebPageAsync before await");
        string webText = await getStringTask;
        Debug.WriteLine("In GetWebPageAsync after await");

        return webText;
    }

    // Output: 
    //   In GetWebPageAsync before await 
    //   In startButton_Click before await 
    //   In GetWebPageAsync after await 
    //   Characters received: 44306
}
```

Comment: You can't mark `Main` with async.

Comment: @JCL:How I can call async/awai method in main method

Comment: You can find all the information about async and await on [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx). I'm not sure you are getting the concept right.

Comment: I know in wpf it's working fine.but for demo I have created console and I want to test in console

Comment: Just get the code you want to call asynchronously out of the `Main` function, and call your function from the code inside `Main`.

Comment: I have a [blog post on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html). You can either install your own context (as I do in my post) or just use `Task.Wait` (as svick does in his answer).

Comment: @user2408588, just for argumente sake, what would you expect to happen if the entry point could be an async method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't specify the 'async' modifier on the 'Main' method of a console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The error message is exactly right: the `Main()` method cannot be `async`, because when `Main()` returns, the application usually ends.

If you want to make a console application that uses `async`, a simple solution is to create an `async` version of `Main()` and synchronously `Wait()` on that from the real `Main()`:

```
static void Main()
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
    // your async code here
}
```

This is one of the rare cases where mixing `await` and `Wait()` is a good idea, you shouldn't usually do that.

**Update**: [Async Main](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main.md) is [supported in C# 7.1](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/Language-Version-History.md#c-71---visual-studio-2017-version-153).

Comment: wait() is void. how to get the result AFTER WAITING ?

Comment: @bilalfazlani What kind of result? `Main()` usually doesn't return anything. In any case, if you have a `Task<T>` (i.e. `Task` with a result), you can use `Result` instead of `Wait()`.

Answer (score 22):

Starting from C# 7.1 there are 4 new signatures for `Main` method which allow to make it `async`([Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/), [Source 2](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/06/CSharp-7.1-a), [Source 3](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/milestone/5)):

```
public static Task Main();
public static Task<int> Main();
public static Task Main(string[] args);
public static Task<int> Main(string[] args);
```

You can mark your `Main` method with `async` keyword and use `await` inside `Main`:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Task<string> getWebPageTask = GetWebPageAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

    Debug.WriteLine("In startButton_Click before await");
    string webText = await getWebPageTask;
    Debug.WriteLine("Characters received: " + webText.Length.ToString()); 
}
```

C# 7.1 is available in Visual Studio 2017 15.3.

Comment: As a footnote, you need to change your project build settings to use the specific minor C# version or it'll default to C#7.0 instead.  This will enable you to use the `async` keyword on `Main`.

Answer (score 3):

### I'm using C# 8 and its working fine.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   var response = await SomeAsyncFunc();
   Console.WriteLine("Async response", response);
}
```

**OR without "await" keyword.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var response = SomeAsyncFunc().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   Console.WriteLine("Async response", response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the code in the link's example and yours, is that you're trying to mark the `Main()` method with an `async` modifier - this is not allowed, and the error says that exactly - the `Main()` method is the "entry point" to the application (it's the method that is executed when your application starts), and it's not allowed to be `async`.

Comment: How I can call async/awai method in main method

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your async code in `MainAsync()` - which is an async function
then call `MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`