# Entry point can be marked with the 'async' modifier on CoreCLR?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, coreclr

In Stephan Cleary's recent blog post about [Async Console Apps on .NET CoreCLR](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/async-console-apps-on-net-coreclr.html) he shows us that in CoreCLR (currently running on Visual Studio 2015, CTP6), the entry point "Main" can actually be marked as `async Task`, compile properly and actually run:

```
public class Program
{
    public async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        Console.WriteLine("Still here!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Gives the following output:

[image: async Main entry point]

This is strengthend by a blog post from the ASP.NET team called [A Deep Dive into the ASP.NET 5 Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn913182.aspx):

> In addition to a static `Program.Main` entry point, the KRE supports
>   instance-based entry points. You can even make the main entry point
>   asynchronous and return a Task. By having the main entry point be an
>   instance method, you can have services injected into your application
>   by the runtime environment.

We know that up until now, [An entry point cannot be marked with the 'async' modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712172/an-entry-point-cannot-be-marked-with-the-async-modifier). So, how is that actually possible in the new CoreCLR runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diving into the source of the CoreCLR runtime, we can see a static class called [`RuntimeBootstrapper`](https://github.com/aspnet/XRE/blob/e282dbf29cae7ac714a5fa6a19b7669f39b113e4/src/dnx.host/RuntimeBootstrapper.cs), which is in charge of invoking our entry point:

```
public static int Execute(string[] args)
{
    // If we're a console host then print exceptions to stderr
    var printExceptionsToStdError = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(EnvironmentNames.ConsoleHost) == "1";

    try
    {
        return ExecuteAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (printExceptionsToStdError)
        {
            PrintErrors(ex);
            return 1;
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

We can see that internally, it calls `ExecuteAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`, which is semantically equivallent to calling `Task.Result`, except that instead of recieveing the wrapped `AggregationException`, we recieve the exception unwrapped.

This is important to understand, as **there is no "black magic"** as to how it's happening. For the current version of the CoreCLR runtime, the method is allowed to marked `async Task` because it's blocked higher up the callchain by the runtime.

### Side Notes:

Diving into `ExecuteAsync`, we'll see that it ends up calling:

```
return bootstrapper.RunAsync(app.RemainingArguments);
```

[When looking inside](https://github.com/aspnet/XRE/blob/1cd7c16acf86f202b260e3da5f200f43967a4be2/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common/Impl/EntryPointExecutor.cs), we see that actual `MethodInfo` invocation of our entry point:

```
public static Task<int> Execute(Assembly assembly, string[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    object instance;
    MethodInfo entryPoint;

    if (!TryGetEntryPoint(assembly, serviceProvider, out instance, out entryPoint))
    {
        return Task.FromResult(-1);
    }

    object result = null;
    var parameters = entryPoint.GetParameters();

    if (parameters.Length == 0)
    {
        result = entryPoint.Invoke(instance, null);
    }
    else if (parameters.Length == 1)
    {
        result = entryPoint.Invoke(instance, new object[] { args });
    }

    if (result is int)
    {
        return Task.FromResult((int)result);
    }

    if (result is Task<int>)
    {
        return (Task<int>)result;
    }

    if (result is Task)
    {
        return ((Task)result).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            return 0;
        });
    }

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```