# Why is async/await not working in my ASP.net 5 Console Application?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library

I tried this simple ASP.net 5 Console Application on both Windows (.NET 4.5.1) and Linux (Mono 4.0.1), both times with the same result.

**Note:** I called it an ASP.net 5 Console Application because that is what is was called in Visual Studio up to RC. Now it is called Console Application (Package), but it still uses DNX from https://github.com/aspnet/dnx :)

My `Program.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public async void Main(String[] args)
        {
            #if DNX451
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
                (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e);
            #endif

            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("After Task.Delay");
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inside Finally");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `project.json`:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {},
    "commands": {
        "ConsoleApplication": "ConsoleApplication"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {}
    }
}
```

When running with either `1.0.0-beta4 CLR` or `1.0.0-beta5-11904 CLR`, the command `dnx . ConsoleApplication` prints nothing. The program exits with status code 0 as soon as it encounters the `Task.Delay`. Even the finally block is never executed.

I couldn't test .NET Core 5.0 because `dnu restore` says everything is OK, but the packages can't be located by the runtime. Oh well...

Does anybody have the same problems with async/await and DNX? Or spot some error I made?

Comment: What happens when you change `Main` to `async Task`?

Comment: `async void` is an anti-pattern outside of event handlers. It's "fire and forget".

Comment: Wait! How does that even work? Your main isn't static ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, yes that supported by DNX.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, that totally works! Can you make this an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you see my question (and answer) in [Entry point can be marked with the 'async' modifier on CoreCLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938582/entry-point-can-be-marked-with-the-async-modifier-on-coreclr), you'll see that at the top-most of the call-stack, you have the following:

```
public static int Execute(string[] args)
{
    // If we're a console host then print exceptions to stderr
    var printExceptionsToStdError = Environment
                                    .GetEnvironmentVariable
                                     (EnvironmentNames.ConsoleHost) == "1";

    try
    {
        return ExecuteAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (printExceptionsToStdError)
        {
            PrintErrors(ex);
            return 1;
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

Internally, it checks to see the return type of the method, if the return type is of type `Task`, then it registers a `ContinueWith`, which it'll be able to synchronously wait on:

```
if (result is Task)
{
    return ((Task)result).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        return 0;
    });
}
```

When you pass in `async void`, it looks to `Execute` as if this method is a "fire and forget" void returning method. That's why it never finishes execution. But, if you change it to return a `Task`, it'll work:

```
public async Task Main(String[] args)
{
    #if DNX451
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
        (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e);
    #endif

    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("After Task.Delay");
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Finally");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that totally makes sense, too.