# Where does async and await end? Confusion

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a program which has no purpose but to help me understand how async and await works. It's a console application which parses XML and waits for a name to be returned, either the surname or the first name. Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Task<string> name = GetFirstParsedName();
     name.Wait();
     if (name.IsCompleted)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(name.Result);
     }

     Console.ReadLine();
 }

static async Task<string> GetFirstParsedName()
{
  string xmlSnippet = @"<person>
<FirstName>Chamir</FirstName>
<Surname>Bodasing</Surname>
<Gender>Male</Gender>
<Nationality>South African</Nationality></person>";

  XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlSnippet);

  XmlParser xmlParser = new XmlParser();
  Task<string> t_GetFirstName = xmlParser.GetFirstName(xmlDoc);
  Task<string> t_GetSurname = xmlParser.GetSurname(xmlDoc);  

  Task<string> t_firstReturnedName = await Task.WhenAny(new Task<string>[] { t_GetFirstName, t_GetSurname });

  string firstReturnedName = await t_firstReturnedName;
  return firstReturnedName;    
}

static async Task<string> GetFirstName(XmlDocument personXml)
{
  string firstName = personXml.SelectSingleNode("//FirstName").InnerText;
  await Task.Delay(5000);
  return firstName;
}

static async Task<string> GetSurname(XmlDocument personXml)
{
  string surname = personXml.SelectSingleNode("//Surname").InnerText;
  await Task.Delay(1);
  return surname;
}
```

It seems like it only makes sense to use the async method when you don't have to return a value to a main method. Unless it means setting a global class property which can then be accessed. If not, in order to await the method, all methods need to be async which in turn means that the return type must be `Task<T>`. It seems like it never ends unless I explicitly have to write the following code (as in above main method):

```
Task<string> name = GetFirstParsedName();
name.Wait();
if (name.IsCompleted)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name.Result);
 }
```

Is my understanding correct at all? I have to use the result property to get the value here and from reading up about this, it seems that this is not the best practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Async on main method of console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/async-on-main-method-of-console-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems like it only makes sense to use the async method when you don't have to return a value to a main method.

Why do you say that? It makes sense to use an async method where-ever you have a naturally asynchronous operation ongoing. No matter if that operation has a return value or doesn't.

> in order to await the method, all methods need to be async which in turn means that the return type must be "Task" . It seems like it never ends

That's correct. Async spreads in your code like a plage, from the [bottom to the top of your stack](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). It usually reaches the highest calling place in your stack (be it a console `Main` method or a UI event handler). That's the advantage of using `async`, it allows you to asynchronously wait an operation while freeing the calling thread. This can help, for example, if you have a WebAPI endpoint which needs to handle a large amount of requests concurrently. If you spend most of your time querying a database, you can free that calling thread in the meanwhile to serve more requests.

> Is my understanding correct at all? I have to use the result property to get the value here and from reading up about this, it seems that this is not the best practice.

You have to use the `Result` property because a console application is a special case, where `Main` cant be marked as `async` (unless [you're using ASP.NET CoreCLR console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938582/entry-point-can-be-marked-with-the-async-modifier-on-coreclr)). If this was a UI event handler or an ASP.NET action, you'd properly `await` the async call.

Comment: Ah so it's just the console that is special. So this means that if I were to have an MVC controller, I could add the async modifier to the method signature and use it under normal async conditions as opposed to the console special case? I'm going to whip up a demo now.

Comment: @downvoter So shed some light on what you find wrong with my answer.

Answer (score 8):

> It seems like it only makes sense to use the async method when you don't have to return a value to a main method. Unless it means setting a global class property which can then be accessed.

Your `async` methods can return `Task<T>` to return a value to its caller. Asynchronous methods do not work very well if they depend on side effects (i.e., setting properties / globals); they work much better if your code is more pure (i.e., taking parameters and returning results).

> If not, in order to await the method, all methods need to be async which in turn means that the return type must be "Task" . It seems like it never ends

This is why one of the central principles of `async` is "async all the way". In most applications, this is exactly what you *should* do. Eventually, the "async chain" generally ends in an `async void` event handler (for UI apps) or an `async Task<T>` entry point (for ASP.NET apps). Console apps are unusual since they do require an explicit `Wait()`/`Result` or equivalent in their `Main` method.

After all, the whole point of `async` is to free up the calling thread. If the next method up the call stack *blocks* that same thread until the `async` code is complete, well, that was a whole lot of work for no benefit...

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the "async all the way". Much easier to understand while having that principle in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `async` keyword let's compiler know that your method is going to execute series of asynchronous calls that should most likely be awaited but should not block the `main` (or UI) thread.

To help you understand async-await a little bit, here is some simple example:

Consider the scenario, when user clicks 'Save' button on WinForm's app, and some UI operation is started asynchronously in different Thread.

The code is :

```
    private Task SomeUIOperation()
    {
        // ui operation
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine));
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.BackColor = Color.Gray));
        });
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await SomeUIOperation();

        // some other stuff
    }
```

If we do not use `async-await`  here UI thread will become unresponsive for 10 seconds.

It's an example of how you usually use async-await, you use it when you want some piece of code to be executed only when asynchronous operation is completed and in the same time you do not want the main thread to be blocked.

And console application is not the best project type for testing and learning Async-Await

Comment: I believe the OP understands what async does. It's the console that causes the confusion. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/async-on-main-method-of-console-app