# How to handle async/await usage in a library called from outside .Net?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm new to this area of C# and, frankly, struggling to grok the paradigm. It seems I'm not alone ([Where does async and await end? Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067874/where-does-async-and-await-end-confusion), http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

In my case I am writing a small TCP server in a C# library, in essence the TCP server should run in its own thread and post data back to the application via a provided callback. So we might have an entrypoint into the library:

```
class MyServer
{
 void StartServerRunningAsync(Callback callback)
 {
  this.callback = callback; //calls back into unmanaged via 'magic' COM interop each time a TCP client posts interesting data
  StartRunningThread(); //this creates a thread to run the server and returns 
 }
 void StartRunningThread()
 {
  new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run)).Start();
 }
 void Run()
 {
  //do standard TCP async stuff treating `Run` like a local `Main`
 }
}
```

This library will be used from an unmanaged C++ application (specifically via COM in this case) which runs the server in the background. So I don't think `StartServerRunning` can/should be `async` but then that means I'm stuck/confused how I can use `async`/`await` at all since it propagates through your whole stack based on the links above.

Is this actually an issue or have I misunderstood something fundamental? How can TPL be encapsulated in this way?

Comment: Is `StartRunningThreadAsync` async as the name suggest? Why? Does it not start a thread as the comment says? Perhaps this helps: [Why is it necessary for every new api to be async?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/396107/45814).

Comment: @Theraot I anticipate it runs up a new thread which is basically a `while(dontQuit)` loop. I don't know if it's `async` that's kind of the point... it seems if I use TPL then it _must_ be? Hence my confusion.

Comment: @Theraot it still seems like there must be a way to 'encapsulate' TPL usage. What if I have an existing codebase that is pre-TPL and I want to plug in some 3rd party library. It feels like I should be able to explicitly run up a separate dedicated thread that then runs that library a bit like my pseudo code above. I'd be interested in an answer expressing this approach if it is feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, using async/await makes things much easier.

```
class MyServer
{
 // notice async void here instead of async Task
 async void StartServerRunning(Callback callback)
  {
   await StartRunningThreadAsync(); // start server asynchronously
   callback();
  }
}
```

From external observer's view, `StartServerRunning` exits immediately as it encounters first await. But in the background, the method is still "running". And once `StartRunningThreadAsync` finishes, the `callback` is then called. This is not be good practice when used inside C# code, but I don't see it as a bad thing when C interop is involved.

I would also recommend to implement exception handling so that no exception can get outside this method. Like :

```
class MyServer
{
 async void StartServerRunning(Callback callback)
  {
   bool wasError = false;
   try{
     await StartRunningThreadAsync(); // start server asynchronously
   }catch(Exception ex)
   {
     // log exception
     wasError = true;
   }
   callback(wasError);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know it makes much difference to your answer but `callback` is called repeatedly during the life of the thread, not when work is finished (well it might be both!). I have absolutely no idea what happens calling an `async` method from outside .Net, you think that would work?

Comment: @Mr.Boy `async void` as far as the rest of the world is concerned is just `void`. In fact, `async` does not exist in IL. Thus, calling it should be the same as calling it if it were just `void`.

Comment: If I understand correctly then, I would not _need_ to explicitly create a dedicated thread at all now. Just use TPL throughout and CLR will ensure threads exist as needed. I updated my question with what I _thought_ would happen if I don't use your approach

Comment: @Mr.Boy That is how it works. One more thing I would worry is what thread the callback is called on. I don't have experience with C interop to tell you exactly what are possible ramifications of running C callback on a CLR thread. So you will need to experiment a bit with that. But that is same if you use plain threads or TPL.

Comment: @Euphoric yeah it's a bit out of scope but IIRC COM actually marshalls all this across threads anyway. When I call a C# method directly from unmanaged C++ over COM it actually runs the C# in a different thread for safety reasons.