# An object is required for the nonstatic field MyMethodAsync

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm trying to learn about `async` and `await` in C#, and have been reading MSDN.  I arrived at [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx#code-snippet-10) which I've copied into a console app in the hope of using the debugger to see how exceptions are handled asynchronously.

Using the info [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16713787/792888), I adapted the MS code to run it in the app (perhaps wrongly as a learner).  The error message I get is on this line:

```
Task<string> theTask = DelayAsync();
```

> CS0120    An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'Program.DelayAsync()'

Is this something I've done wrong, or a bug in the MSDN code? Can anyone please explain how to run the `DoSomethingAsync()` method from a console app so that I can see in the debugger how the exception is returned please?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DoSomethingAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        Task<string> theTask = DelayAsync();
        try
        {
            string result = await theTask;
            Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Task IsCanceled: " + theTask.IsCanceled);
        Debug.WriteLine("Task IsFaulted:  " + theTask.IsFaulted);
        if (theTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Task Exception Message: " + theTask.Exception.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine("Task Inner Exception Message: " + theTask.Exception.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> DelayAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        //throw new OperationCanceledException("canceled");
        //throw new Exception("Something happened.");
        return "Done";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling from a static method, the called method should be static or you need to create an instance of the class Program and call through that instance. Find more info in the duplicate

Comment: With respect, the question doesn't provide an easy answer for someone learning C# or async, given that async was introduced in VS2012 and the question was asked in 2009.  Although the error is the same, the cause is somewhat different.  However, your accompanying advice *does* provide enough to go on, so thank you.

Comment: `static void Main()` changed to an async button click event handler in a Windows form, which works fine.