# async Main wouldn't compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.1

created blank Console app:

```
namespace ClientUI
{
    class Program
    {
        static async void Main(string[] args)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler throws:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS5001  Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable
>   for an entry
>   point

I read this article https://www.meziantou.net/2017/08/24/4-ways-to-enable-the-latest-c-features async Main is a C# 7.1 feature, ok, so I go to project properties >> Build >> Advanced and select Language version: C# 7.1

Trying to build again, but the error remains.

Comment: Did you try having a non-namespaced `Main()` function?

Comment: Main can not be *async*

Comment: @Eser it can be now : https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/c5fbcd6f4ecdd2cda0cf4403cc0a4090acfd279c/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main.md

Comment: Make it `static async Task`, not `async void`.

Comment: Evk, thanks, this whole async thing is so not natural :( so damn confusing

Comment: Note for that dupe marked by @Jerodev that the accepted answer is outdated. Relevant is https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908959/982149

Comment: @monstro what is really not natural is all that old `BeginDoThing`, `EndDoThing`, `DoThing().ContinueWith(x => DoOtherThing().ContinueWith(y => ...))))`. After a little bit practice you will be surprised how did you live without async before. It's implementation in C# is so good that many other languages (such as javascipt) copied it.

Comment: @Evk, sure, but I am not talking about old ways of doing this, it was nightmare, but this async-await pair that forces escalation of async all the way up the stack is confusing, maybe u'r right, I have to get used to it