# Cannot create an async Main

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make the `Main` async, so I tried:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Books books = new Books();
        await books.AddBooksAsync();
    }
}
```

where `AddBooksAsync` have this structure:

```
public async Task AddBooksAsync()
{
  //some contents
}
```

I get this error:

> Does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An entry point cannot be marked with the 'async' modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712172/an-entry-point-cannot-be-marked-with-the-async-modifier)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't specify the 'async' modifier on the 'Main' method of a console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app)

Comment: It compiles fine for me. Please update your question to include a screenshot of your `Advanced Build Settings` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/advanced-build-settings-dialog-box-csharp .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your visual studio by default will  be setted to this 
[image]
Which means that the major version will  be 7.0 and not 7.1  you should force it to 7.1 in order to compile it with the 7.1 version

The  second option in Project Properties=> Build =>advanced set the language version to  C# latest minor version(latest)

Comment: Great, it made my day.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your csproj.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```