# Having a problem getting Microsoft Graph call to work within a .net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-ad-graph-api

The following Code works within a console application.

```
public Boolean Graph_IsMemberOfGroup(string Parm_AzureUserID, string Parm_GroupID) {
        Boolean Lcl_ReturnValue = false;
        Task<string> Lcl_Response = GraphPriv_IsMemberOfGroup(Parm_AzureUserID, Parm_GroupID);
        if (Lcl_Response.Result != null) {
            Lcl_ReturnValue = Lcl_Response.Result.Contains(Parm_GroupID);
        }//end if
        return (Lcl_ReturnValue);
    }

    private async Task<string> GraphPriv_IsMemberOfGroup(string Parm_AzureUserID, string Parm_GroupID) {
        string Lcl_Returnvalue = null;
        var Lcl_Uri = "https://graph.windows.net/CleMetroSchools.onmicrosoft.com/users/" + Parm_AzureUserID.Trim() + "/checkMemberGroups?api-version=1.6";
        string Lcl_RequestBody = @"{""groupIds"": [""" + Parm_GroupID.Trim() + @"""]}";
        Global_HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Global_Token.Result);
        HttpResponseMessage Lcl_PostResult = await Global_HttpClient.PostAsync(Lcl_Uri, new StringContent(Lcl_RequestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        if (Lcl_PostResult.Content != null) {
            Lcl_Returnvalue = await Lcl_PostResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }//end if

        return Lcl_Returnvalue;
    }
```

The call I use is

```
if (Graph_IsMemberOfGroup(CurrentUser,Group)){
```

The problem I am having is that when I Use the same code in a plain (not MVC) ASP.net web application.  The system does not wait for GraphPriv_IsMemberOfGroup to completed before it tries to process the  if (Lcl_Response.Result != null) {

Anything I have tried so far with waits either will not compile or waits forever.
I have been searching for several days and all I have managed to do is travel deeper down the rabbit hole of confusion.

Comment: If the exact same code works in an ASP.NET application, it is by sheer luck. Take a look at [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: You are not using `await` when you call `GraphPriv_IsMemberOfGroup`...try adding `await` on `Task<string> Lcl_Response = await GraphPriv_IsMemberOfGroup(Parm_AzureUserID, Parm_GroupID);`

Comment: Still, you should follow the recommendation from @Stijn and try to do more research and training, before using the async-await pattern.

Comment: I tried  Task<string> Lcl_Response = await GraphPriv_IsMemberOfGroup(Parm_AzureUserID, Parm_GroupID);   but get the compile error  The 'Await' operator can only be used within an asysnc method.

Comment: I have read and re read async and await but I am still unsure what to do.   Please understand that I have been trying to figure this out since August.   I cannot tell you the number of hours I have spent watching youtube videos and reading web pages trying to figure out how to do one thing.  (Verify that a user is a member of an AD group)  Much of what I read is either outdated or only has snippets of code that leave a lot of important parts out.

Comment: It's not a simple concept, especially for beginners. But I'm afraid SO isn't the place to teach it to you. If you're not making any progress with your own research (videos and web pages), consider asking someone in real life, taking an actual course with a teacher, or perhaps find a decent book.

Comment: If I had someone in real life I wouldn't be asking here!  After 30 years of coding including writing drivers in assembly language I never thought I would have this much trouble making an HTTP call from a web application.    I am the sole employee developer of almost 30 years at an Urban school district.  (The trend is to buy packages or outsource out of country)  I have been using C# since it first came one scene, and this is the first time I have ever needed to make an HTTP call from a web app.

Comment: Have you considered using the [Microsoft.Graph NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph)? It should deal with the HTTP calls for you. You'll still need to understand async/await but you might have an easier time when you don't have to spend time on the low-level details. I haven't taken a detailed look at the library, but it does seem to contain methods to call the `checkMemberGroups` endpoint.

Comment: Also, sorry if I offended you in any way with that comment yesterday, it was not my intention.

Comment: Thanks for the Microsoft Graph package suggestion.   I will look into it.

Comment: I know I need sometype of between  

Task<string> Lcl_Response = GraphPriv_IsMemberOfGroup(Parm_AzureUserID, Parm_GroupID); 

and
        if (Lcl_Response.Result != null) {  

but

             Task<string> Lcl_Response = await GraphPriv_IsMemberOfGroup(Parm_AzureUserID, Parm_GroupID);  

and  

await Lcl_Response will not compile.  (I have tried to make the whole procedure an async but that only move the problem to a different location.)

Lcl_Response.wait(); waits forever.

In any case I am going to try Microsoft Graph package

Comment: Worst case I write windows applications to write out all the groups I am concerned about and ther members to a SQL table.  (I have an the windows side of this working for sometime with all sorts of call to Graph)  Since I have around 50,000 accounts I will have to cycle through them as I will not be able to hit everyone in a single night.   Downside is when changes are made children may not have access for days until a long term solution can be found.

Comment: Yes, using async/await usually means you have to make everything up to the top also use async/await. It's possible to avoid it but they're advanced scenarios. The good news is that it *is* possible today to make a console application easily use async/await. Take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456208/cannot-create-an-async-main) to enable using `static async Task Main` instead of `static void Main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misapplying the async/await model here. You shouldn't be looking for a `Task<string>`, you should be looking for `string` from an awaited method:

```
public async Task<Boolean> Graph_IsMemberOfGroup(string Parm_AzureUserID, string Parm_GroupID) {
    Boolean Lcl_ReturnValue = false;
    string Lcl_Response = await GraphPriv_IsMemberOfGroup(Parm_AzureUserID, Parm_GroupID);
    return Lcl_Response.Result.Contains(Parm_GroupID);
}
```

An async method returns a value wrapped in a `Task<>`, The `await` keyword tells the code to wait for the method to return and unwrap the response. So if an async method returns `Task<string>` then you would call that method using `string s = await method()`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The problem I having with the code as you have provided is giving me compile error on the await line as follows.


Error CS4032 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<bool>'. GraphTest

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit. You need to turn `Graph_IsMemberOfGroup` into an async method. This enables the async/await framework.

Comment: If I turn that into an async then the same overall problem moves up a level to a protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) Which I cannot make an async :( in order for it to wait for the task to finish.   Wondering if this has actually been done in a web app.

Comment: What platform/framework are you using? You should be able to set up your event handlers as async as well

Comment: Thank you, Thank you Thank you!