# Wait for async Task without wrapping exceptions in AggregateException

Tags: c#, async-await

I am using a library which provides methods ending with `...Async` and return `Task`. I am going to use these in a **command line application**. So I need to call them synchronously a lot.

C# of course does not allow calling these methods in `Main` method since you cannot use `async` modifier on `Main` method. Assume this is the task:

```
var task = datastore.Save(data);
```

I found several solutions like:

```
Tasks.WaitAll(task);
task.Wait();
```

however all these wrap thrown exceptions in `AggregateException`, **I don't want that**. I just want to say `task.Result` and I expect the original exception to be thrown.

When I use a method returning `Task<TResult>`, `task.Result` throws `AggregateException` even though there are no continuation tasks set. Why is this hapening?

I also have tried,

```
task.RunSynchronously();
```

it gives error:

> RunSynchronously may not be called on a task not bound to a delegate, such as the task returned from an asynchronous method.

so I guess that's not for methods marked as `async`.

Any ideas on patterns using libraries designed for async apps in console apps where there is no asynchronous context?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> I am going to use these in a command line application. So I need to call them synchronously a lot.

No, you don't. You *can* use `async`-`await` in a console application, you just need to make an async to sync transition at the very top. And you can do that by using `Wait()`:

```
public static void Main()
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
}

public static async Task MainAsync()
{
    var datastore = …;
    await datastore.SaveAsync();
}
```

Usually, combining `await` with `Wait()` is a bad idea (it can cause deadlocks), but it's the right solution here.

Note that if `SaveAsync()` throws an exception and you don't catch it, it will be rethrown as `AggregateException` from the `Wait()`. But you can catch it as the original exception in `MainAsync()` (because it doesn't use `Wait()`).

If you really wanted to get the first exception thrown directly, you could do something similar to what `await` does: `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. Note that if the `Task` contains more than one exception, you will get only the first one (but the same applies to `await`).

Since C# 7.1, you can make your `Main` method `async` and the compiler will write the transition code for you:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var datastore = …;
    await datastore.SaveAsync();
}
```

> When I use a method returning `Task<TResult>`, `task.Result` throws `AggregateException` even though there are no continuation tasks set. Why is this happening?

This has nothing to do with continuations. A single `Task` can represent multiple operations, and each of them can throw an exception. Because of that, `Task` methods *always* throw the exceptions wrapped in an `AggregateException`.

> I also have tried `task.RunSynchronously()`

That doesn't make any sense. `RunSynchronously()` can only be used on `Task`s that were created using the `Task` constructor. That's not the case here, so you can't use it. `Task`s returned from async methods are always already started.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dummy `Main`

```
public static void Main()
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
}

public static async Task MainAsync()
{
    try {
        var result = await dataStore.Save(data);
    } catch(ExceptionYouWantToCatch e) {
       // handle it
    }
}
```

Also, see this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212343/1529246

Answer (score 1):

As of C# 7.1 you can now declare the Main method as async.  Just have to make sure your language is either set to default major version (which should work in VS 2019 now) or you can always target a specific version of the language.

See this link for details. [Turn on async main](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2017/12/08/async-main-is-available-but-hidden/)