# Awaiting a second level Task<IEnumerable<Something>> in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, enumerable, async-await

I ran into a peculiar problem. Basically I'm writing a wrapper for an existing asynchronous class that reads data from the server. The original method that is in the library is something like this

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PersonData>> GetPersonData();
```

It works splendidly with this

```
var people = await GetPersonData();
```

However, I run into a problem when I try to wrap it. For the sake of simplicity, I've included the initial version I tried to test it which didn't work and furthermore, my actual wrapping method gives a peculiar "Cannot await" error that doesn't indicate the actual reason as to why it can't be done. It is a compiler error, so I must be doing something wrong.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PersonData>> GetWrappedPersonData()
{
    return await clientClass.GetPersonData();
}
```

And then when I call this in my main class

```
var wrappedPeople = await wrapper.GetWrappedPersonData();
```

I get an error of the "await" stating that "Cannot await 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<PersonData>>'

When I hover over the GetWrappedPersonData, it says the method is awaitable. I am confused as to why I can't await this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source of the problem though, it was the fact that this whole thing consists of a plurality of different projects. The communication module of it contains multiple different libraries to separate service providers. The returned "PersonData" resided in one of these assemblies and was not referenced from the main app project. The error I received didn't really reflect that this was the root cause.

So basically the error I received gave very little hint towards what was actually wrong with the solution. Hope this helps someone else out there receiving the same error. :P

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a compiler message error though.

But the solution is you should not `await` in your wrapper :)

If you `await` it you unwrap the task, and you can't `await` an already awaited task :)

Comment: Thanks. The actual thing that I want to do though is to handle unwrapping the task in the wrapper handler and process the data to a neater format, so I do want to await it in the wrapper. I found the source of the problem though, it was the fact that this whole thing consists of a plurality of different projects. The communication module of it contains multiple different libraries to separate service providers. The returned "PersonData" resided in one of these assemblies and was not referenced from the main app project. The error I received didn't really reflect that this was the root cause...

Answer (score 0):

You need `async` on your calling method.  If that method is `Main`, then see this answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212343/171121

Comment: Calling method had async on it. I found the root cause of this error (see my answer below). I don't know why I didn't get a missing reference exception though. When I changed the return type from the persondata to a custom class, I could await it properly.