# Async/await flow

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have written the following (a plain Console application) to test my understanding about async and await in C#.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Async result: " + getLengthFromWebsiteAsync());
    }

    public static async Task<int> getLengthFromWebsiteAsync()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        Task<string> sampleTask = httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.adobe.com");

        Console.WriteLine("Before the await: ");

        int lengthRequired = (await sampleTask).Length;
        Console.WriteLine("After the await: " + lengthRequired.ToString());
        return lengthRequired;
    }
```

The following is the result that I got upon running:

```
Before the await:
Async result: System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1[System.Int32]
```

My question is, isn't the line "After the await: " supposed to show up? Am I on the wrong track in understanding the flow of async/await?

Comment: You still have to `await getLengthFromWebsiteAsync()`. Async in a console app is a bit tricky though, see [Async on main method of console app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9208921/247702).

Comment: You're too happy too early.  Ask for the task's Result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently you're *starting* the operation - but it's never completing. Your program is terminating before you do anything with the task.

As this is a console app, continuations will run on a thread-pool thread anyway, so you can change your code to make the `Main` method block until the task has completed:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Async result: " + getLengthFromWebsiteAsync().Result);
}
```

Normally you should be *very* careful about using `Result` and `Wait()` on tasks, as you can easily cause a deadlock. (For example, it wouldn't be safe to do the above in a WinForms UI - the `Result` call would block the UI thread until the task completed... and the task would be waiting for the UI thread to become available to run the continuation after the `await` in the async method.)