# Bootstrapper class not found in Nito.AsyncEx

Tags: vb.net

Please see the answer to the following question: [Can't specify the 'async' modifier on the 'Main' method of a console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/async-on-main-method-of-console-app)

I am trying to do this with a VB.NET program.  I have added the package using NUGET and I have ensured that the Reference is added.  Please see the code below:

```
Imports Nito.AsyncEx

Public Class ScheduledTasks
    Private Shared Async Sub MainAsync(args As String())
        Dim bs As New Bootstrapper()
        Dim list As VariantType = Await bs.GetList()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The error is: Type BootStrapper is not found.  I have used Intellisense to look at the types contained in Nito.AsyncEx and Bootstapper is not there? How do I create an asynchronous main method using VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

`Bootstrapper` is not a part of AsyncEx. `AsyncContext` is:

```
Imports Nito.AsyncEx

Public Class Program
    Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        AsyncContext.Run(Function() MainAsync(args))
    End Sub
    Private Shared Function MainAsync(args As String()) As Task
        ...
    End Function
End Class
```