# HttpClient - A task was cancelled?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

It works fine when have one or two tasks however throws an error "A task was cancelled" when we have more than one task listed.

[image]

```
List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>();
allTasks.Add(....);
allTasks.Add(....);
Task.WaitAll(allTasks.ToArray(), configuration.CancellationToken);


private static Task<T> HttpClientSendAsync<T>(string url, object data, HttpMethod method, string contentType, CancellationToken token)
{
    HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url);
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(Constants.TimeOut);

    if (data != null)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Helper.ToJSON(data));
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd(), Encoding.UTF8, contentType);
    }

    return httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        var response = task.Result;
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(stringTask =>
        {
            var json = stringTask.Result;
            return Helper.FromJSON<T>(json);
        });
    }).Unwrap();
}
```

Comment: What does the Inner Exception say?

Comment: Why do you take a `CancellationToken` as parameter and not use it?

Comment: The reason for me was disposing `HttpClient` by mistake, e.g
`async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Method(){
using(var client = new HttpClient()) return client.GetAsync(request);
}`

Comment: For those using `HttpClient` like @JobaDiniz (with a `using()`), please stop! The reason: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: This is the latest Microsoft recommendation on `HttpClient`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Answer (score 380, accepted):

There's 2 likely reasons that a `TaskCanceledException` would be thrown:

1. Something called `Cancel()` on the `CancellationTokenSource` associated with the cancellation token before the task completed.
2. The request timed out, i.e. didn't complete within the timespan you specified on `HttpClient.Timeout`.

My guess is it was a timeout. (If it was an explicit cancellation, you probably would have figured that out.) You can be more certain by inspecting the exception:

```
try
{
    var response = task.Result;
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
{
    // Check ex.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested here.
    // If false, it's pretty safe to assume it was a timeout.
}
```

Comment: So what is a possible solution? I have  a similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937328/get-asp-net-mvc5-webapi-token-fails-sometimes?noredirect=1#comment61434357_36937328

Comment: @Dimi - this is pretty old, but the solution I used was to set the Timeout property to a larger value: `httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)`

Comment: @RQDQ, you the man, man! Not using the constructor solved the problem for me. In my specific case, I wanted a timeout in milliseconds. Using `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Configuration.HttpTimeout)` as opposed to `new TimeSpan(Configuration.HttpTimeout)` worked a treat. Thanks!

Comment: @RQDQ `httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)` isn't a good approach, because it will block that particular thread for 30 minutes and will also not hit the HTTP endpoint (which is your main task). Also, if your program finishes before 30 mins then you are most likely to encounter `ThreadAbortException`. A better approach would be finding out why that HTTP endpoint isn't being hit, it might require VPN or some restricted network access.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay Calls made off `HttpClient` are asynchronous so there's no thread blocking no matter how long you set the timeout, as long as you're using it correctly (i.e. `await`ing the response).

Comment: @ToddMenier Yes, what I meant to say is that particular thread responsible for network operation will be blocked for no reason for 30 mins (I wasn't talking about the main UI thread)

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay If the call is `await`ed, then _no thread_ is blocked. Not the UI thread, not a threadpool thread other background thread, none.

Comment: @ToddMenier Really appreciate you dispelling the thread blocking myth on this.

Comment: In my case, ex.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested was false even when it was canceled via cancellation token. Anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 30):

I ran into this issue because my `Main()` method wasn't waiting for the task to complete before returning, so the `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` was being cancelled when my console program exited.

### C# ≥ 7.1

You can [make the main method asynchronous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-71) and await the task.

```cs
public static async Task Main(){
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> myTask = sendRequest(); // however you create the Task
    HttpResponseMessage response = await myTask;
    // process the response
}
```

### C# < 7.1

The solution was to call `myTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in `Main()` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212343/979493)).

Comment: GetAwaiter().GetResult() will block all operations on current thread until it has the result, be careful

Comment: Are you telling if you do this change the code will throw timeoutexception instead of TaskCancelled? In our scenario we need to get TimeoutException as we are calling third party APIs.

Answer (score 25):

```
var clientHttp = new HttpClient();
clientHttp.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
```

The above is the best approach for waiting on a large request.
You are confused about 30 minutes; it's random time and you can give any time that you want.

In other words, request will not wait for 30 minutes if they get results before 30 minutes.
30 min means request processing time is 30 min.
When we occurred error "Task was cancelled", or large data request requirements.

Answer (score 17):

Another possibility is that the result is not awaited on the client side. This can happen if any one method on the call stack does not use the await keyword to wait for the call to be completed.

Answer (score 12):

Promoting @JobaDiniz's comment to an answer:

*Do not* do the obvious thing and dispose the `HttpClient` instance, even though the code "looks right":

```cs
async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Method() {
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
    return client.GetAsync(request);
}
```

Disposing the `HttpClient` instance can cause following HTTP requests started by other instances of `HttpClient` to be cancelled!

The same happens with C#'s new RIAA syntax; slightly less obvious:

```cs
async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Method() {
  using var client = new HttpClient();
  return client.GetAsync(request);
}
```

---

Instead, `HttpClient` interface is a bit crufty, and the [**correct way to use it in dotnet core 2.1+**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#recommended-use) is:

> Use a static or singleton `HttpClient` instance with `PooledConnectionLifetime`...

Basically, cache a static instance of `HttpClient` for your app or library, and reuse it:

```cs
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Method() {
  return client.GetAsync(request);
}
```

(The `Async()` request methods [are all thread safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient).)

---

However, Microsoft [recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#issues-with-the-original-httpclient-class-available-in-net) ***you don't use don't directly use  `new HttpClient()`!*** Instead for both dotnet core and .NET Framework, use `IHttpClientFactory`. One caveat: the docs for `IHttpClientFactory` are often for ASP.NET apps but [it is possible to use it any CLI/GUI app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52622586/771768).)

(For .NET Framework, "you can add the [Microsoft.Extensions.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/) NuGet package to any .NET Standard 2.0-compliant project" --see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51480287/771768).)

Comment: For anyone else reading this, this also applies to .NET Framework and not just .NET Core. Relevant documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#recommended-use)

Comment: I doubt that keeping a static reference to a disposable object is the correct approach. Rather follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests and use the IHttpClientFactory.

Comment: @Dejan Microsoft says keeping a static reference is the correct way to use the HttpClient footgun. Tried to add enough helpful links, thanks to you and somethingRandom for that context! I agree that API is crufty, so I tried to update my answer with IHttpClientFactory, but I'm not familiar with that so I didn't try to include a code sample. Feel free to edit in any fixes.

Comment: @CarlWalsh thanks for the update a linking the static-field approach with docs to back it up. And sorry for my wrong guess here. However, it hopefully helps others to not discard your answer too early.

Answer (score 6):

in my .net core 3.1 applications I am getting two problem where inner cause was timeout exception.
1, one is i am getting aggregate exception and in it's inner exception was timeout exception
2, other case was Task canceled exception

My solution is

```
catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.InnerException is TimeoutException)
                {
                    ex = ex.InnerException;
                }
                else if (ex is TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    if ((ex as TaskCanceledException).CancellationToken == null || (ex as TaskCanceledException).CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
                    {
                        ex = new TimeoutException("Timeout occurred");
                    }
                }                
                Logger.Fatal(string.Format("Exception at calling {0} :{1}", url, ex.Message), ex);
            }
```

Comment: Would be `ex.InnerException  is TaskCanceledException`?

Comment: Also IsCancellationRequested would be true?

Answer (score 2):

In my situation, the controller method was not made as async and the method called inside the controller method was async.

So I guess its important to use async/await all the way to top level to avoid issues like these.

Answer (score 1):

I was using a simple call instead of `async`. As soon I added `await`  and made method `async` it started working fine.

```
public async Task<T> ExecuteScalarAsync<T>(string query, object parameter = null, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text) where T : IConvertible
        {
            using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_con))
            {
                return await db.ExecuteScalarAsync<T>(query, parameter, null, null, commandType);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another reason can be that if you are running the service (API) and put a breakpoint in the service (and your code is stuck at some breakpoint (e.g Visual Studio solution is showing **Debugging** instead of **Running**)). and then hitting the API from the client code. So if the service code a paused on some breakpoint, you just hit F5 in VS.