# Unexpected end of request content Kestrel ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a problem with sending large (20GB) file between two WebApi.

WebAPI1 written in `ASP.NET 4.6`

WebAPI2 written in `ASP.NET Core 2.0`

When I am sending this file via Postman to WebAPI2 whole file is send. But when I am trying to send the file from WebAPI1 to WebAPI2 it fails (I am able to send files like 7GB though).

During sending 20GB file I am receiving error in WebAPI2:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected
 end of request content.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompl
etion.ThrowFailed()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetR
esult(ReadResult& result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.Micr
osoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.IReadableBufferAwai
ter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.ReadableB
ufferAwaitable.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.<ReadAs
ync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.FrameRequestStream.
<ReadAsyncInternal>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.BufferedReadStream.<EnsureBufferedAsync>
d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.<ReadAsync>d__36.M
oveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at System.IO.Stream.<CopyToAsyncInternal>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run this request as part of WCF contract in WebApi1 I got stacktrace:

```
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
```

However I noticed that Exception was thrown always after 2 minutes...

Than I tried to send that 20GB file as part of controller method (from WebAPI1) and catched there `TaskCanceledException`. When this exception occurs, we can tell was that a timeout issue by checking the flag `IsCancellationRequested` if it is `false` it means that it is timeout issue. 
Helpful post here: 
[HttpClient - A task was cancelled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179848/httpclient-a-task-was-cancelled/29214208#29214208)

In my case `TaskCanceledException` in stacktrace was set to `false`, so it was timeout in HttpClient

```
new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2) };
```

increasing the limit to 10 minutes resolved the issue.