# How do I implement IHttpClientFactory in .net framework apart from .Net core?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-core-2.0

In .Net core, we can use IHttpClientFactory to inject and use during runtime. As a developer I no need to worry about the dependency resolution. I need to just specify AddHttpClient() in service collection.
Likewise, how can I use IHttpClientFactory in WPF application, .net framework 4.6.1? As there is no Service collection available for WPF application, not getting how to resolve the dependency.

Comment: @ChrisPratt it's a .NET Standard 2.0 package, it's available on any compatible runtime

Comment: .NET Standard 2.0 is https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdBCY.png Then see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0

Comment: "Targeting a higher version of .NET Standard allows a library to use more APIs but means it can only be used on more recent versions of .NET. Targeting a lower version reduces the available APIs but means the library can run in more places." -https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/dotnet-standard#versions

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can add the [Microsoft.Extensions.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/) NuGet package to any .NET Standard 2.0-compliant project. That includes projects that target .NET 4.6.1

All of the Microsoft.Extensions.* packages are .NET Standard 2.0 packages, which means you can use the same Configuration, Dependency Injection, Logging services as .NET Core.

Microsoft.Extensions.Http provides the HttpClientFactory *only*, not the new optimized HttpClient. This is only available in .NET Core 2.1

Comment: The article explaining `IHttpClientFactory` says the problem is that the default `HttpClient` in **.NET Core**  (with no mention made of .NET Framework) will cause socket-exhaustion issues - does the default `HttpClient` in .NET Framework 4.8 have this issue or not? If it doesn't, then there's no need to use `IHttpClientFactory` in .NET Framework projects and they can use a long-life'd singleton `HttpClient` instance, no?

Comment: @Dai I think the issue exists in both implementations. Both the [4.8](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.Http.HttpClient)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.8#remarks) and 3.1 docs mention the issue. Can't link both URLs are too long. Without doing a test it is safer to use the factory.

Comment: @Dai no - in fact the issue is the opposite of that. Socket exhaustion is [caused when you *don't* reuse an instance](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). The OS keeps sockets for up to 240s after you dispose an HttpClient waiting for any remaining remote packets. When you reuse an instance, you reuse the *socket* to a specific *machine* which means [any DNS changes will be missed](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Comment: According to [microsoft httpclient guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/httpclient-guidelines), in **Recommended use** section, it says in .NET Framework, you can create a new HttpClient each time you need to send a request.

Comment: @Topman it says "If you create a new client instance for each request, you can exhaust available sockets." You do _not_ want to create a new HttpClient for each request, because you'll exhaust sockets.

Comment: @Topman you can and *should* reuse HttpClient instances. It's not just the socket exhaustion issue. By reusing HttpClient you don't have to wait for DNS resolution on every request.

Comment: I would like to add that the recommended approach:
Long Lived requests should use a "static or singleton" POOLED HttpClient. For Short Lived requests use IHttpClientfactory.. The POOLING implementation is different in dotnet framework / dotnet core 5+.
In dotnet framework use the ServicePointManager in dotnet core/5+ use PooledConnectionLifetime.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines

Comment: @ReidK that's not what the linked document says. It doesn't matter how long a request will take. Recycling won't interrupt active requests. Recycling is used to handle DNS changes which affects long and short requests equally.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - what does it mean exactly when you say "Microsoft.Extensions.Http provides the HttpClientFactory only, not the new optimized HttpClient. This is only available in .NET Core 2.1"?

Comment: @Topman I know what you mean, I've used it for reference many times but the guidelines has changed recently.