# IHttpClientFactory Singleton .NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, singleton, httpclient, httpclientfactory

**Scenario**

I am trying to change my existing `HttpClient` to `IHttpClientFactory`. When I verified the existing code, its using using{...} statement which causes issues and it is mentioned [here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). So I thought of implementing singleton Http client and reached another blog related to this and it is [here](http://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html).

From all these, I understood that the best one is [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1) introduced in .NET Core.

**Implementation Plan**

As this application is in ASP.NET MVC 4 and does not use DI, I have to do something to use without the DI framework. Based on my search, got answers from StackOverflow and planned to implement the same way. Meanwhile, I also got another project, which already removed all the dependencies and is ready to use in earlier projects without doing all things. The repo is [`HttpClientFactoryLite`](https://github.com/uhaciogullari/HttpClientFactoryLite).

**Question**

Now I can use `HttpClientFactoryLite` by initializing this class? The description also mentioned it can be used along with the existing DI framework so that `ClientFactory` can be registered as a singleton. Please find the wordings from the readme

```
using HttpClientFactoryLite;

var httpClientFactory = new HttpClientFactory(); //bliss
```

> If you are using dependency injection, make sure that IHttpClientFactory is registered as a singleton.

In my scenario, I don't have any DI framework added. So I am going to initialize the factory wherever I needed. Here I am confused that in 2 things

1. Is it necessary to make a singleton class for `HttpClientFactoryLite`?
2. How is this `HttpClientFactory` class disposed? Is there a need to dispose of it as part of the controller or same using statement etc?
3. Based on the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51474776/how-do-i-implement-ihttpclientfactory-in-net-framework-apart-from-net-core),  `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` provides the HttpClientFactory only, not the new optimized HttpClient. This is only available in .NET Core 2.1. So any difference in implementing IHttpClientFactory?

Please advise

Comment: Just call `AddHttpClient` on the service collection, you don't need a *DI framework* or any other third-party library (potentially just an MS nuget) if you are not in core. From there you can just create a singleton for `httpclientfactory` if you need. or even easier just put `IHttpClientFactory` in your constructor when you want to use it

Comment: @MichaelRandall Thank you for the response. So you mean I need to create Singleton class implementation for HttpClientFactory as I am not using any DI framework?

Comment: @Akhil I humbly suggest you, you just write a static wrapper class for HttpClient, if your requirements are basic.

Comment: @SafakUlusoy hmm seems ok. But I just want to understand the new factory as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET 3.1:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpClientFactory, HttpClientFactory>();
}
```

ASP.NET will automatically pass the correct singleton to controllers which demand an IHttpClientFactory in their constructor.

---

Poormans variation without DI-Container:

```
public static class Singleton<TInterface> 
{
    private static TInterface instance;
    public static TInterface Instance
    { 
        get => instance;
        private set => instance ??= value;
    }

    public static void Add<TConcrete>() where TConcrete : TInterface, new()
        => Instance = new TConcrete();

    public static void Add<TConcrete>(TConcrete instance) where TConcrete : TInterface
        => Instance = instance;

    // put dispose logic if necessary
}
```

Usage:

```
// Application Entrypoint
Singleton<IHttpClientFactory>.Add<HttpClientFactory>();

// Class/Controller Property
private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory 
    = Singleton<IHttpClientFactory>.Instance;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this is fine in dot net core. I asked how this achieved in asp.net MVC 4 and not used any DI framework?

Comment: The second part of my answers covers how to do this yourself with an ASP.NET version that doesn't integrate DI and without a DI-Framework.
Just copy and paste the static Singleton class and use it as shown under 'Usage:'.

Comment: Looks good. I will check thank you. So I need Singleton configuration in the Global.asax. Is my understanding right? As I am using IHttpClientFactory,  dispose  not needed (my assumption). is this right? Also just want to confirm, is this thread-safe

Comment: With the provided code you don't need any further configuration for the singleton.
As IHttpClientFactory does not implement IDisposable, you don't need any disposal logic.

Comment: Thanks. Will check in the code. Could you check my third question? Any comments on that. Or can I use the regular HttpClient by using this approach?

Comment: Yes, static initialization is thread-safe in C# and the setter doesn't assign anything if not null.
If you want to be ultra-sure, you can refactor the "Instance" property in a nested static class and assign once upon that class-initalization.
I wouldn't bother though, this is fine.

Comment: Thanks. just comment on my question 3. Which one you prefer

Comment: Go with the HttpClientFactory of your HttpClientFactoryLite package with my provided code - as the mentioned issues with HttpClient were the reason you wanted to change this in the first place. :)

Comment: Coukd rewrite the colaesing assignmnet in c# 7.3

Comment: private set => instance = instance ?? value; - you are reassigning the same instance whenever this is set again, but that shouldn't happen anyway and it's shorter.
Alternatively you can just write it the long way:
private set { if (instance == null) { instance = value; } }

Comment: I wrote like that. Just want to confirm. thanks for the help

Comment: @Purity  static initialization is thread-safe in C# if you provide a public static constructor. read this great Jon Skeet post: https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton#lazy