# Why is my .net core API cancelling requests?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a an aync method that is looped:

```
    private Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponseMessage(Region region, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var longLatString = $"q={region.LongLat.Lat},{region.LongLat.Long}";
        var startDateString = $"{startDateQueryParam}={ConvertDateTimeToApixuQueryString(startDate)}";
        var endDateString = $"{endDateQueryParam}={ConvertDateTimeToApixuQueryString(endDate)}";
        var url = $"http://api?key={Config.Key}&{longLatString}&{startDateString}&{endDateString}";
        return Client.GetAsync(url);
    }
```

I then take the response and save it to my ef core database, however in some instances I get this Exception message: The Operaiton was canceled

I really dont understand that. This is a TCP handshake issue?

Edit:

For context I am making many of these calls, passing response to the method that writes to db (which is also so slow Its unbelievable):

```
private async Task<int> WriteResult(Response apiResponse, Region region)
        {
            // since context is not thread safe we ensure we have a new one for each insert
            // since a .net core app can insert data at the same time from different users different instances of context
            // must be thread safe
            using (var context = new DalContext(ContextOptions))
            {
                var batch = new List<HistoricalWeather>();
                foreach (var forecast in apiResponse.Forecast.Forecastday)
                {
                    // avoid inserting duplicates
                    var existingRecord = context.HistoricalWeather
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.RegionId == region.Id &&
                            IsOnSameDate(x.Date.UtcDateTime, forecast.Date));
                    if (existingRecord != null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var newHistoricalWeather = new HistoricalWeather
                    {
                        RegionId = region.Id,
                        CelsiusMin = forecast.Day.Mintemp_c,
                        CelsiusMax = forecast.Day.Maxtemp_c,
                        CelsiusAverage = forecast.Day.Avgtemp_c,
                        MaxWindMph = forecast.Day.Maxwind_mph,
                        PrecipitationMillimeters = forecast.Day.Totalprecip_mm,
                        AverageHumidity = forecast.Day.Avghumidity,
                        AverageVisibilityMph = forecast.Day.Avgvis_miles,
                        UvIndex = forecast.Day.Uv,
                        Date = new DateTimeOffset(forecast.Date),
                        Condition = forecast.Day.Condition.Text
                    };

                    batch.Add(newHistoricalWeather);
                }

                context.HistoricalWeather.AddRange(batch);
                var inserts = await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return inserts;
            }
```

Edit: I am making 150,000 calls. I know this is questionable since It all goes in memory I guess before even doing a save but this is where I got to in trying to make this run faster... only I guess my actual writing code is blocking :/

```
var dbInserts = await Task.WhenAll(
                getTasks // the list of all api get requests
                .Select(async x => {
                    // parsed can be null if get failed
                    var parsed = await ParseApixuResponse(x.Item1); // readcontentasync and just return the deserialized json
                    return new Tuple<ApiResult, Region>(parsed, x.Item2);
                })
                .Select(async x => {
                    var finishedGet = await x;
                    if(finishedGet.Item1 == null)
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    return await writeResult(finishedGet.Item1, finishedGet.Item2);
                })
            );
```

Comment: How many requests are you submitting at one time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpClient - A task was cancelled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179848/httpclient-a-task-was-cancelled)

Comment: 150, 000 api calls

Comment: I thought timeouts gave a different status code rather than throw exception like that.. ok thanks

Comment: The main issue is you are doing more concurrent requests than the value of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: the requests did get created though since the api has logged them :/

Comment: They will get created - but just like your browser blocks (i.e. delays) requests if you do too many, so will your C# code - unless you set `DefaultConnectionLimit` to much higher. If you block enough of them, some of them will start to timeout (as you are seeing). Set the `DefaultConnectionLimit` to a larger number (e.g. 100) and ensure you submit only 100 requests at a time.

Comment: @Craig Your GetResponseMessage method doesnt implement the async tag in its declaration, is this on purpose?

Comment: yes I think my understanding of tasks is just so poor i was trying to pass that task along a chain without awaiting and then run them all at the end to achieve parallel... but the parse needs the get, the write needs the parse, so its not parallel at all its just a giant loop on 1 thread that keeps spawning immediately awaited task threads and does not run parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.net core has a `DefaultConnectionLimit` setting as answered in comments.

this limits outgoing connections to specific domains to ensure all ports are not taken etc.

i did my parallel work incorrectly causing it to go over the limit - which everything i read says should not be 2 on .net core but it was - and that caused connections to close before receiving responses.

I made it greater, did parallel work correctly, lowered it again.