# Is it true, when you Dispose the HttpClient instance can cause following HTTP requests started by other instances of HttpClient to be cancelled?

Tags: c#, httpclient

Based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65400954/11065063

and we also have this issue in our production system, we have an instance as singleton in our DI container, plus we also have old codes that creating new instance inside using statement, and we are encountering transient errors that the request has been cancelled and we don't have any idea how's that happening.

Comment: If you are using .NET Core, read up on the IHttpClientFactory patterns

Comment: Unfortunately we are using .NET Framework but we are trying find ways to implement HttpClientFactory

Comment: In any case, the discussion around IHttpClientFactory will give you insight to the issues surrounding IHttpClient

Comment: Only if you use static class which I do not recommend.  The link has a static class.