# Get TResult from Task<TResult>

Tags: c#, task, entity-framework-6

I have a problem using async, and Task.

I have this function:

```
public async Task<List> Read(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new SmartFridgeContext())
        {
            var list = await db.Lists.Include(l => l.ListItems.Select(li => li.Item)).SingleOrDefaultAsync(l => l.ListId == id);
            return list;
        }
    }
```

Been trying for hours, but I don't know how to get a `List` from `Task<List>`. What I mean, is that I want the "pure" list back, so I can use it.

Can anyone help?

EDIT:

To clear up confusion, this is a List:

```
public class List
{
    public int ListId { get; set; }
    public string ListName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; } 

    public List(string listname)
    {
        ListName = listname;
    }
}
```

I know I will need to `await` the `Task`, but then I need to declare the function `async`. What if I want to call `Read(int id)` in Main()?

Comment: You need to `await` the task.

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the task.

Use it like this:

```
List myList = await Read(5);
```

If you want to use it in the Main method, the compiler won't let you await the method. Use this:

```
List myList = Read(5).Result;
```

Comment: What if I for an example wants to call that in Main()? Then the compiler tells me to make the method Async.

Comment: @Thisen - that's an entirely different question, now you're asking how you can call async methods from main  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/async-on-main-method-of-console-app

Comment: @Thisen `var x = Read(5).Result`

Comment: When I use the code you told me to, the Task.WaitAll(myTask) gives me an AggregateException.

Comment: @Thisen - also see http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html

Comment: I'm probably confused about something, but `List myList = Read(5).Result;` gives me a AggregateException too.

Comment: @Thisen My guess is that there's something wrong with the Read method. Maybe it was cancelled or something.

Comment: @Thisen then put a break-point and see the inner exceptions. How can we help if you get an exception in your Read method which is not clear for us what it is doing.

Comment: @Thisen - an "AggregateException" means that the real exception is in the InnerException (or maybe even the InnerException of another InnerException) so you have to look deeper.

Comment: @EZI Just made this method (for test): `public static Task<List> Reader(int id)
        {
            var manage = new ListManager();
            return manage.Read(id);
        }`
Which gives me no exceptions, so it seems like there's nothing with th Read method.

Comment: @Thisen OK, I say your original method returns expections not your test case.  If you insist to say "a correct method returns exception",  good to learn a new thing every day.