# How to async this long running method?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have this method which I would like to run asynchronously so that I can do other things while it runs. It does not rely on any other Async method (it doesn't call out to another resource, download a file or anything). I would like to avoid using `new Task()`, `Task.Factory.StartTask()` and `Task.Run()`, if possible.

Is it possible to run this method asynchronously, with tidy, readable code and without using Task explicitly?

If not, what is the tidiest way of running the method asynchronously?

Note: Please don't be concerned with the silly logic in the method - I have boiled it down to be deliberately slow but not show my actual code.

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
  RunMySlowLogic();
}

private void RunMySlowLogic()
{
  while (true)
    for (int i=0; i<100000000;i++)
      if (i == new Random().Next(999))
        return true;
}
```

Currently, I believe that I would need to wrap the method in a lambda or Task and mark it async. Where would the await go?

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617702/how-to-async-this-long-running-method

Comment: Console programs can't `await`.

Comment: If you just want to run this code in a separate thread, and it does not need to wait on any other async methods, then you can just do `Task.Factory.StartNew(RunMySlowLogic)`. You can add the `LongRunning` flag if you like as well.

Comment: *If not, what is the tidiest way of running the method asynchronously?* Your method does nothing async. You want to run code in parallel. Why don't you want to use `Task.Run`?

Comment: sievajet You linked to my post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/async-on-main-method-of-console-app

Comment: scott chamberlain I know main() methods can't be awaited, but I am not calling it from there.

Comment: odyss-jii Is it possible to avoid StartNew()? I would like to use nothing but async and await keywords, but is that possible or am I forced to create a Task object somewhere in my method?

Comment: Yuval - I know, this is just an example. My real code is more complex, but too long and proprietary to post here. I would like to know the cleanest way of async'ing that method, without using Task, if possible.

Comment: Matt - Using `async-await` will not help here, your method isn't asynchronous. We cant help you *asyncify* this code since this example makes no sense at all.

Comment: Yuval - But it can be run on another thread. Call it the background, if you like, but that's what I'm aiming at.

Comment: @MattW You do that with `Task.Run`.

Comment: @i3arnon - What is the cleanest way of doing that?

Comment: @MattW as I posted in my answer: `Task.Run(() => RunMySlowLogic());`

Comment: Matt - I think you might have a miss-understanding of what `Task.Run` does. You want to avoid it for some reason, but that's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're confusing two different things. You can run this in the background, and this method can be asynchronous. These are 2 different things and your method can do either, or both.

If you do something asynchronous in that method, like `Task.Delay` or some non-blocking I/O then call that method, await the returned task and make the method itself async:

```
async Task RunMySlowLogicAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // ...
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

If you don't have such a thing then your method isn't asynchronous, it's synchronous. You can still run it in the background on a different (`ThreadPool`) thread while you do other things using `Task.Run`:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => RunMySlowLogic());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of executing code asynchronously in the .NET environment. Have a look at the [Asynchronous Programming Patterns MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx).

Tasks are to make your job easier. I think the only valid reason to avoid using tasks is when you are targeting an older version of .NET.

So without Tasks, you can start a thread yourself, or use a [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4732ks0.aspx) (Tasks do this internally).

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
  var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RunMySlowLogicWrapped, are);
  // Do some other work here
  are.WaitOne();
}

// you have to match the signature of WaitCallback delegate, we can use it to communicate cross-thread
private void RunMySlowLogicWrapped(Object state) {
  AutoResetEvent are = (AutoResetEvent) state;
  RunMySlowLogic();
  are.Set();
}

private bool RunMySlowLogic() 
{
  while (true)
    for (int i=0; i<100000000;i++)
      if (i == new Random().Next(999))
        return true;
}
```

Comment: RunMySlowLogic can return true? it is a gambling. after 999, it could never return true.

Comment: @NuriYILMAZ I didnt eve notice that, just copied that from the question.