# Using async void method to run long-living operation

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Is it appropriate to use `async void` method to start some long-living operation? I know [Nito](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212343/1763111) or `Task.Run()` could be used to Run *Task* from non-async method. What is the difference? Are there any pitfalls?

By all that I mean, can I write like that:

```
async void bar()
{
    try
    {
        //...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // no rethrowing here
    }
}

void foo()
{
    bar();
    // will continue right after 1st await in bar()
    baz();
}
```

Comment: Why not do `async Task` and just not await bar?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain But will it start asynchronously if not awaited later in code?

Comment: Doing async void and doing async Task without awaiting the returned task has the exact same behavior. calling await does not start a task, it waits for a already started task to finish. That is why if you call await on a task that was started with `new Task()` and never had `.Start()` called on it the await will wait forever because the task is not running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case it would be better to use `async Task` to get better error handling behavior. You don't need to await the resulting task.

In your code snippet the comment `will continue right after 1st await in bar` is not necessarily correct. As it stands `bar` will synchronously execute and block `foo` because `bar` has no awaits in it.

Starting a long running operation requires to either use async IO or to use a new thread/task in some way (`Task.Run` is appropriate).

Comment: +1 I recall Stephen Toub's comment on async/await: "no keyword in c# starts a thread - there should be some API call (Task.Run(), File.ReadAsync()....)"