# Is this statement true about C# / .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I was thinking about the fact that `Main` can't be marked `async`. Is it true that in C#

> "The entry point of your application must be synchronous."

Or what is a more rigorous and correct way of saying what I'm trying to say?

I'm trying to convey the idea that if you deep enough down the chain of execution, you must reach a synchronous process at the end of the chain.

Comment: That's the shallowest point in the execution though, not the deepest.

Comment: Why would you want to convey completely wrong idea? Quoted statement makes sense by itself, but it does not match what you are saying afterwards...

Comment: @JonHanna Yes, you're right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't specify the 'async' modifier on the 'Main' method of a console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app)