# How do I use an async method provided in an API?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, synchronous

As a simple example, I would like to show all users in a database, and the API provides the async method `ShowUsersAsync()`.

```
public async Task<InfluxResult<UserRow>> ShowUsersAsync()
/// SHOW all existing users and their admin status.
```

Now, I am trying to do the following.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new InfluxClient(new Uri("http://localhost:8086"));

        **//"How do I run it here?"** TestAsync

        Console.WriteLine("PRINT ALL USERS");
    }

    public async void TestAsync(InfluxClient client)
    {
        var users = await client.ShowUsersAsync();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something about async and await?

API reference:
https://github.com/MikaelGRA/InfluxDB.Client

Comment: Note that async/await is not good in console applications in the `Main` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't specify the 'async' modifier on the 'Main' method of a console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app)

Comment: Where do you actually intend on using the api? Because using it in a console application isn't a good example if it is not the intended platform. Also `TestAsync` should return `Task`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation at the link provided in OP accessing the API should look like this in your intended application.

```
public async Task<InfluxResult<UserRow>> TestAsync() {
    var client = new InfluxClient(new Uri("http://localhost:8086"));
    var users = await client.ShowUsersAsync();
    return users;
}
```

Though the simple example in the OP uses a Console Application, the assumption here is that the console application is not the eventual final system to be developed.

But if it is then have a look at this article : [Async Console Programs](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html)

the above code would be used in your final program as

```
var users = await TestAsync();
```

If at this time the intention is just to test the API then Unit Tests may be a good candidate.

```
[UnitTest]
public class InfluxClientTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task InfluxClient_Should_Get_All_Users() {
        //Arrange        
        var client = new InfluxClient(new Uri("http://localhost:8086"));
        //Act
        var users = await client.ShowUsersAsync();

        //Assert
        //...verify expected results.
    }
}
```

The test(s) can be run/debugged in the test runner and the behaviors verified with out the limitations of the console application.

Comment: This is great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
TestAsync(client).Wait();
```