# How to enable C# 7 features in existing projects

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I am not sure how to use new C# 7 features in existing solution. I tried using pattern matching in a switch statement but I keep getting `Value of integral type expected` error.

Is there a trick to enable it? I though I can just use new features if I open the solution in VS 2017.

My projects are targeting .net 4.6.2.

Here is the sample code

```
    private void CS7Test(object o)
    {
        switch (o)
        {
            case null:
                Console.WriteLine("it's a constant pattern");
                break;
            case int i:
                Console.WriteLine("it's an int");
                break;
            case UserInfo p when p.Username.StartsWith("Ka"):
                Console.WriteLine($"a Ka person {p.Username}");
                break;
            case UserInfo p:
                Console.WriteLine($"any other person {p.Username}");
                break;
            case var x:
                Console.WriteLine($"it's a var pattern with the type {x?.GetType().Name} ");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

[image: Code with errors]

Comment: Could you include some code demonstrating this error? Aside from needing to add the value tuple nuget package, all that's needed to use C# 7 is to open it in BS2017.

Comment: @DavidArno added sample code.

Comment: Project Properties | Build | Advanced... | Language version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it's working without doing any special config. Resharper was giving those errors and after disabling the resharper it worked like a charm.

Comment: Yes. You can control the language version used by each project, but since the "default" language version (which most people use by default) was updated to C# 7.0 in VS2017, it should work automatically.

For C# 7.1, we'll provide a lightbulb experience to help with changing the language version (since "default" means "latest major version").

Answer (score 1):

Vs 2017 is configured by default to support c#7.0 with enabling Resharper.
You need not to disable it.

In vs 2017 update 3 you can configure it to use the new features of c# 7.1 (and resharper is enabled also).

For more details review: [setting c#7.1 in vs2017.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46290692/3142139)

Comment: Add manually to.csproj  the property   `<LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>`  works for me.