# C# Async Tasks wait vs await

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

There is something that is bugging me for a while, something that happen in my code I can't understand.

I've defined a workflow to extract information from the `Facebook API`, basically I have 3 different `async tasks`.

**Execute Reports**

```
private static async Task<List<DataTypes.ReportRun>> ExecuteMarketingReports(FacebookClient fb, List<DataTypes.Request.Batch> batch_requests)
{
//Do stuff - Make async POST requests to 
//FB to execute reports on FB server side
}
```

**Monitorize Reports**

```
private static async Task<List<DataTypes.AdReportRun>> MonitorizeMarketingReports(FacebookClient fb, List<DataTypes.ReportRun> tListReportRun)
{
  //Do stuff -- Check if the reports are ready or not, and return a list with status
}
```

**GetReportData**

```
private static async Task GetReportData(FacebookClient fb, List<DataTypes.AdReportRun> tListReportRun, DateTime since, DateTime until, string breakdown)
{
//Do stuff -  Gets report thata once the reports are finish and create the files
}
```

This is the main Task where all the other methods are called

```
 private static async Task PullInsightsData(FacebookClient fb, List<DataTypes.Request.Batch> batchRequests, DateTime since, DateTime until, string breakdown)
{
    var tResult = new List<DataTypes.AdReportRun>();
    int retry = 0;
        List<DataTypes.AdReportRun> tReportCompleteList = new List<DataTypes.AdReportRun>();
        List<DataTypes.AdReportRun> tReportIncompleteList = new List<DataTypes.AdReportRun>();


        var report_ids = await ExecuteMarketingReports(fb, batchRequests);
        Thread.Sleep(20000); // Waits 20 seconds before get the info.
        do
        {
            /*Start monitorizing the reports*/
            var tReport_info = await MonitorizeMarketingReports(fb, report_ids);

            /*Get the reports that are complete*/
            tReportCompleteList = tReport_info.Where(x => x.async_percent_completion == 100).ToList();

            if (tReportCompleteList.Count > 0)
                 await GetReportData(fb, tReportCompleteList, since, until, breakdown);

            tReportIncompleteList = tReport_info.Where(x => x.async_percent_completion < 100).ToList();

            report_ids = (from x in tReportIncompleteList
                          select new DataTypes.ReportRun { report_run_id = x.id }).ToList();

            var sleepTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retry + 1));
            Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
            retry++;
        } while (report_ids.Count > 0 && retry < 8);
}
```

I call my Main task in this `foreach` loop, and this is where the problem occurs.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ActiveAdAccounts.Count; i = i + 50)
{
    var AdAccountsSubList = ActiveAdAccounts.Skip(i).Take(50).ToList();

    var batchRequests = ....

await PullInsightsData(fb, batchRequests, (DateTime)since, (DateTime)until, breakdown.Replace(",", "_"));
    //tTaskList.Add(PullInsightsData(fb, batchRequests, (DateTime)since, (DateTime)until, breakdown.Replace(",", "_")));   
}
//Task.WaitAll(tTaskList);
```

I don't understand why the `foreach` loop does't continue using the `await` the console application closes suddenly, shouldn't `await` "wait" until the task is finish and so then proceed to the next line of code?

I've solved the problem putting all the tasks into a list and waiting for all, but I would like an explanation for this.

**[EDITED]** Question was edited to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How and When to use \`async\` and \`await\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Comment: If duplicated I apologize, I haven't find other questions related to mine.

Comment: Please include a minimal, reproducible example. There's no `await` in your `for`/`foreach` loop right now. `await` does in fact pause the method until that task completes. The most common causes of "early return" are using `StartNew` (use `Task.Run` instead), `ContinueWith` (use `await` instead), or `async void` (use `async Task` instead).

Comment: @StephenCleary I would include it but it's way to complex to include all the code into this question. I'm not sure how to make it more clear to you guys.

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues What you need to do is create a *minimal* reproducible example. In other words, delete code (or replace with stub operations like `Task.Delay`) until it is as small as you can get it. At each step, verify that the incorrect behavior still happens. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've edited my question to create a minimal reproducible example. I Hope you guys understand what I mean this time.

Comment: Side comment:  in async functions, do not call `Thread.Sleep()`.  Instead do `await Task.Delay()`.  `Sleep` will synchronously block your thread and defeat the purpose of using async/await in the first place.  `Task.Delay()` will allow you to "wait for some time to go by" in an async friendly way.

Comment: check this one for Console App https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app