# Await in Main method - Who gets the control until Task is completed?

Tags: c#, async-await, program-entry-point

Await before an uncompleted Task will pass the control to the caller, until the Task is completed.

When you use it in Main() who is going to get the control?

```
public static async Task Main()
{
   await F1() ;   //This await will pass the control to ???           
}

public static async Task F1()
{
   await Task.Run(()=>{...}) ;   //This await will pass the control to Main()      
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219114/what-is-the-point-of-having-async-main#comment91167598_46219318

Comment: @GSerg Hi, Thanks for the comment but the link you supplied doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It does. It describes in simple English the relevant line of code from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46219318/11683) it's posted under. That same line of code is now reposted in an [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63812720/11683) too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The primary thread that *keeps your app alive* is effectively:

```cs
private static void TheRealEntryPoint() => Main().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

(which is broadly the same as `.Wait()`, and is the kind of "sync-over-async" thing that you should never write in your own code, but ... which suffices in this specific scenario)

As such:

- the `Task.Run` returns an incomplete task
- thus the `await` on that returns to the caller, taking us back to `Main()`
- in an incomplete state, so *that* `await` also returns to the caller - so we end up in `TheRealEntryPoint`
- where the primary thread simply blocks
- ...
- at some point, the thread-pool picks up the work item and runs it
- marking the task as complete
- which reactivates `F1`, which can now mark *itself* as complete
- which reactivates `Main`, which can now mark *itself* as complete
- which unblocks the primary thread that is stuck in `TheRealEntryPoint`
- which allows the exe to terminate

Comment: Is TheRealEntryPoint() just the standard Main()? , which means the thread will blocked in the standard Main()?

Comment: @SItzik it is a method invented bv the compiler; the name is irrelevant, but it isn't actually `Main` - the compiler can mark anything it likes as the entry-point. In a local test, it is actually called `<Main>()` (with the angle brackets), making it unpronouncable in regular C#