# How can I wait for the asynchronous method result before execute the rest of the main thread?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, download

I would like to download a file with asynchronous method, in order
to show the actual progress of the download to the user.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void downloadFile(string url)
        {
            Object LockObject = new Object();

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                int left = Console.CursorLeft;
                int top = Console.CursorTop;

                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
                {
                    lock (LockObject)
                    {

                        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                        Console.Write(e.ProgressPercentage + "%");

                    }
                };

                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"c:\asd");
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => downloadFile("http://download.lsoft.net/ActiveDataStudioSetup.exe"));
            task.Wait();

            //There can be lots of funcs after download......
            //!!!
            Console.WriteLine("\nIt should be seen ONLY after the full download"); 

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

The download procedure seems to be fine, file is getting and I also see the actual state of that, but after the method called, everything will be executed right after the calling, but the main thread should wait the complete of the download first.

Comment: You merely need to await the task. For example, you can say `await task` instead of `task.Wait()`

Comment: Take a look at the async await keywords introduced in C# 5

Comment: @JDDavis incorrect. **Main** is not async

Comment: Apologies, he could move the task out of main, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app)

Comment: @MickyD It is now. (C# 7.1)

Comment: You also might want to use IProgress.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt oooooh nice.  Well the one above isn't. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `downloadFile` method is an asynchronous `void` method.  The method just starts an asynchronous operation and returns immediately, but it doesn't provide any way to inform the caller when it has completed.  That you *start* the asynchronous operation in another thread and then wait for it to finish *starting* the asynchronous operation in your main method before continuing doesn't result in it waiting for it to *complete* the download, as you're seeing.

You need to alter your download file so that it returns a `Task` that indicates when it's finished:

```
public static Task DownloadFile(string url)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            lock (client)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                Console.Write(e.ProgressPercentage + "%");
            }
        };
        return client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), @"c:\asd");
    }
}
```

Then of course there's no reason at all to start it from another thread.  You  just call the method to start the download:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Task task = DownloadFile("http://download.lsoft.net/ActiveDataStudioSetup.exe");
    task.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("\nIt should be seen ONLY after the full download");

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Exit. . . ");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```