# C# Async Sockets - Code Analysis

Tags: c#, console-application, asyncsocket

My client part is closing after I do a request to server a second time, but without errors, it just goes away:

```
class Client
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Title = "Client";
            AsyncClient client = new AsyncClient(60101);
            client.Connect();
            Console.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}

public class AsyncClient
{
    private IPAddress ipAddress;
    private int port;

    /// <summary>
    /// Connects to the local IPAddress.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="port"></param>
    public AsyncClient(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        this.ipAddress = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < ipHostInfo.AddressList.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ipHostInfo.AddressList[i].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                this.ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (this.ipAddress == null)
            throw new Exception("No IPv4 address has been found");
    }

    public AsyncClient(string ip, int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
        IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out ipAddress);
    }

    public async void Connect()
    {
        int attempts = 0;
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        while (!client.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                attempts++;
                client.Connect(this.ipAddress, this.port);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                await Process(client);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Attempts: {0}", attempts);
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task Process(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a Request: ");
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(Console.ReadLine());
                string response = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                if (response != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!tcpClient.Connected)
            {
                for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Connection lost, trying to reconnect in {i}");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                Connect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This under is the server side code, it's just for study purpose. I am trying to learn how to work with sockets and after trying with many different ways like "begin" methods, etc, I feel like I've finally found the right way to do it, since with the others I had problems like concurrent access, closing connection, etc, but this time I believe I got it right.
Am I wrong or this time it's really all good with my code?

```
class Server
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            AsyncServer server = new AsyncServer(60101);
            server.Run();
            Console.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}

public class AsyncServer
{
    private IPAddress ipAddress;
    private int port;

    public AsyncServer(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        this.ipAddress = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < ipHostInfo.AddressList.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ipHostInfo.AddressList[i].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                this.ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (this.ipAddress == null)
            throw new Exception("No IPv4 address for server");
    }

    public async void Run()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(this.ipAddress, this.port);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine($"Server is now online on Port: {this.port}");
        Console.WriteLine("Hit <Enter> to stop the service");
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                Process(tcpClient);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private async void Process(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        string clientEndPoint = tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine($"Received connection request from {clientEndPoint}");
        try
        {
            NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            while (true)
            {
                string request = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                if (request != null)
                    Handle(request, writer);
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //
        }
        finally
        {
            if (tcpClient.Connected)
                tcpClient.Close();
            Console.WriteLine($"{clientEndPoint} has closed the connection, aborting operation");
        }
    }

    private string Response(string request)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000); 
        if (request.ToLower() == "get time")
            return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        else
            return $"\"{request}\" is a invalid request";
    }

    private async void Handle(string request, StreamWriter writer)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received request: {request}");
            string response = Response(request);
            Console.WriteLine($"Computed response is: {response}");
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(response);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Plus, I would like to know, if I want to make it work on my external IP, so ppl from different IPs can use it, what should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My client part is closing after I do a request to server a second
>   time, but without errors, it just goes away:

The reason for this is that your client calls async method `client.Connect()`, but doesn't (a)wait this method, so execution on the main thread continues to the next line, `Console.Read()`, which blocks only until you press *[ENTER]* for the second time (first *[ENTER]* is consumed by `Console.ReadLine()` in a `Process()` method). Then there is nothing for main thread to do and main thread (as well as whole client application) exits.

*As a side note, it is good practise to name all async methods such that it's name ends with 'Async', so that caller of such a method is aware of it's async behaviour and doesn't forget to (a)wait the method. So you should rename `Connect` to `ConnectAsync` and `Process` to `ProcessAsync`.*

Solution is to change return type of `Connect` method to `Task`, making method awaitable (it is strongly discouraged for async method to return `void` anyway):

```
public async Task ConnectAsync()
```

and add `.Wait()` in the `Main` method, which blocks main thread, until `ConnectAsync()` exits.

```
client.ConnectAsync().Wait();
```

In C# 7.1 you could also use async Main instead:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    await client.ConnectAsync();
    ...
}
```

> Plus, I would like to know, if I want to make it work on my external
>   IP, so ppl from different IPs can use it, what should I change?

Just make sure that if server has more than one IP address, `TcpListener` listens on the correct one, and enable port or application in the firewall.

Comment: Duly noted the tip about naming convention.

I didn't know I could use ".Wait" on tasks, this saved my life, thank you very much.
About making Main Method async, It does not allow me, I don't know why, my visual studio is 100% updated but it still fails, even if I change Task for Void, it fails to compile but with no warning or error message.

How do I know which one is the right IP Adress?

Comment: Even latest Visual Studio uses C# 7.0 by default. You have to manually enable C# 7.1 in project properties - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46290692/1286670