# Mvc cancel Jquery Ajax request from server side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, azure-sql-database

I have one scenario where I need to perform search operation from database and show result on webpage. User have webform to type & search food from `Sql Server` Database. So here I want to cancel previous ongoing search operation and continue with new search.

For e.g. first User type **tea** and request sent to Mvc `ActionResult` using `Ajax`. So now request is in process and user type **Tea with milk** so at that time I want to cancel previous request and continue with new request.

I have below `Jquery` code to send request to Mvc `ActionResult` with `abort()` functionality.

```
var xhr = null;
function searchFood(o, q, f) {
    if(xhr && xhr.readyState != 4){
        console.log(xhr);
        xhr.abort();
    }
    xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/food/foodsearch/",
        data: {
            o: o,
            q: q,
            filters: f
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            showSpinner();
        },
        success: function (a) {
            try {                        
                xhr = null;
            } catch (c) {
                xhr = null;
            }
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            xhr = null;
        },
    });
}
```

When user finish typing I call this `searchfood` method. Take a look at my server side `c#` code

```
[HttpGet]
[AjaxOnly]
public async Task<PartialViewResult> foodsearch(int o, string q, string filters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    CancellationToken disconnectedToken = Response.ClientDisconnectedToken;
    var source = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, disconnectedToken);

    //some local veriable declared
    model.foods = filters.ToLower() == FoodFilterTypes.b_food || filters.ToLower() == all_categories ? await SearchFoodAsync(o, maxLimit, FoodModel.b_food, q, null, null, source.Token) : new List<Food>();
}

/// <summary>
/// search foods
/// </summary>
/// <param name="offset"></param>
/// <param name="limit"></param>
/// <param name="q"></param>
/// <param name="filters"></param>
/// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[NonAction]
protected async Task<List<Food>> SearchFoodAsync(int offset, int limit, string filters, string q, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    DataTable dtblFood = await LSocialBL.SearchFoodAsync(offset, limit, filters, q, cancellationToken);
    //--- few more code lines
    if (dtblFood != null)
    {
        foods = dtblFood.ToList<Food>();
        //dispose object
        dtblFood.Dispose();
        dtblFood = null;

        Parallel.ForEach(foods, new ParallelOptions { CancellationToken = cancellationToken }, async (f) =>
        {
            f.images = await GetFoodImagesAsync(f.id, cancellationToken);
        });
        //for (int i = 0; i < foods.Count; i++)
        //{
        //  foods[i].images = await GetFoodImagesAsync(foods[i].id);
        //}
    }
}
```

Here my `LSocialBL.SearchFoodAsync`method execute database operation like below.
I am executing stored procedure to fetch results.

```
using (IDataReader drdFood = await objSqlDatabase.ExecuteReaderAsync(objSqlCommand, cancellationToken))
{
    dtblFoods.Load(drdFood);
}
return dtblFoods;
```

Here I am sending cancellationtoken to cancel existing db operation. It is necessary for me to cancel db operation as I have huge data of foods. I debug client request and it shows like below

[image]

I think this is really simple scenario so I have searched a lot for this but didn't find any useful links or examples. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756553/how-can-i-abort-an-action-in-asp-net-mvc) but I am not getting how this implementation help me to cancel db operations or cancel previous old request. Can someone help me to workout this?

Comment: I don't know why this question received downvote.

Comment: Check [This](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/07/19/cancelling-long-running-queries-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-api.aspx) may be helps

Comment: @NaDeRStar I have already tried this. Please check my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created the following example using ASP.NET MVC 5 and I checked both SQL Profiler and Network tab in developer tools and I can confirm it is working well and the database server also receives cancellation and cancels query execution.

Please consider, the same solutions will work with EF as well, but since in the post `DataTable` has been used, I also wrote the example using `DataTable`.

### ASP.NET MVC 5 - Cancellation Example

In the following example, I've created a simple index page, containing a textbox. When you type in `TextBox`, it waits for 500 milliseconds to detect if you have stopped typing. Then after if detected you have stopped typing, it sends an ajax request for search.

If you start typing again (or you have delays more than 500 ms) between keystorkes, it cancels the request and query execution will also cancels at database level. You can see it using profiler.

***Table1Business.cs***

I suppose you have a database containing `Table1` which has `Id` and `Name` columns. So I create a business logic class for search between records of `Table1` by making a bit delay in the query.

Note: The delay is just for example, to simulate a long running query.

In the following code, connection has been opened async, reader executed async, and also as reader has been read async:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class Table1Business
{
    public async Task<DataTable> Search(string name,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Your connection string"))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'; " +
            "SELECT TOP 10 [Id], [Name] " +
            "FROM [Table1] WHERE [Name] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'", connection))
        {
            var table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = name;
            await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
            var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken);
            while (await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken))
            {
                object[] values = new object[2];
                reader.GetValues(values);
                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

***HomeController.cs***

The following controller, has a simple `Index` action to return `Index` view and a `Search` action which is responsible for performing the search and also receiving the cancel pulse. In case of cancellation, the execution will be cancelled even in database. In this [post](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/07/19/cancelling-long-running-queries-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-api.aspx), you can find more information about the cancellation.

```
using CancellationExample.Models;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public async Task<ActionResult> Search(string name, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        CancellationToken disconnectedToken = Response.ClientDisconnectedToken;
        var source = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, 
            disconnectedToken);
        DataTable dt = null;
        var business = new Table1Business();
        dt = await business.Search(name, source.Token);
        return PartialView(dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Name")));
    }
}
```

***Index.cshtml***

The way that I detect end of typing borrowed from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48679579/3110834). It's just for example, you can use any other solution based on your preference. I personally prefer to rely on an enter rather than trying to detect change of typing.

Anyway, in the following code, we check if `xhr` is not null, it means there is another ajax request in progress, and then we abort it:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div>
    <form action="/home/search" method="get" id="form">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var xhr = null;
        var timeout = null;
        $("#name").keyup(function () {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            if (xhr != null)
                xhr.abort();
            timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                xhr = $.get("/home/search?name=" + $("#name").val(), function (data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                });
            }, 500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

***Search.cshtml***

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>@item</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried your code looks like previous `task` is cancelling. I have tried same code before but it didn't worked. I don't know why. Only change in your code is that you have passed default parameter i.e. `CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)` to `Search` method. and one more thing you have called `xhr.abort()` before `timeout` function which I have written inside `settimeout` function. only two differences.

Comment: Please check my edited method i.e. `SearchFoodAsync`. I have added few code line which was not there in previous code. I fetch food images from database same like `searchfood` so I want to know, do I need to pass same cancellation token to `GetFoodImagesAsync`? As it is sub method of `SearchFoodAsync`, is it required to pass `Cancellationtoken` to all those sub methods?

Comment: You're welcome, I didn't compare the code, but what I shared here, is tested and works properly. About the cancellation token, you need to pass the cancellation token down to all methods, so all the methods can be informed of the cancellation.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. is it not required to set `null` to `xhr`?

Comment: I've already set it to null at the beginning. We can set it to `null` again after aborting.

Comment: You mean in `abort` event?

Comment: `xhr.abort();` can be followed by setting `xhr = null` but not necessarily, because above code is working. Anyway, it's just a PoC code and you may want to make it more robust based on your production environment. Hope it helps you and future readers :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186519/discussion-between-ajay-p-and-reza-aghaei).

Answer (score 1):

Here the code

```
   [HttpGet]
    [AjaxOnly]
    public async Task<PartialViewResult> foodsearch(int o, string q, string filters)
    {
        //some local veriable declared
        model.foods = new List<Food>();


        if (filters.ToLower() == FoodFilterTypes.b_food
        || filters.ToLower() == all_categories)
        {
            var gotResult = false;
            var tokenSource1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken ct1 = tokenSource.Token;
            CancellationToken ct2 = tokenSource.Token;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                await SearchFoodAsync(o, maxLimit, FoodModel.b_food, q, null, null, ct2);
                gotResult = true;
            }, ct1);

            while (!gotResult)
            {
                // When you call abort Response.IsClientConnected will = false
                if (!Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    tokenSource1.Cancel();
                    tokenSource2.Cancel();
                    break;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10);
            }

        };
        return PartialView();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// search foods
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="offset"></param>
    /// <param name="limit"></param>
    /// <param name="q"></param>
    /// <param name="filters"></param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [NonAction]
    protected async Task<List<Food>> SearchFoodAsync(int offset, int limit, string filters, string q, CancellationToken ct2)
    {
        var dtblFood = await LSocialBL.SearchFoodAsync(offset, limit, filters, q, ct2);
        //--- few more code lines
    }
```

Comment: Mohamed, Stackoverflow works different from forums. To add more details to your answer, you can easily edit your answer and add more details. You don't need to post another answer.

Answer (score -1):

### Step 1 : Get the Session ID

```
Select @@SPID ;
```

### Step 2 : Kill The Session ID

```
    Kill 50 ;
```

### Step 3 : Proof  that the sql request is killed

if you run the code below you will get

> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill
>   state.
>
> severe error occurred on the current command.  The
>   results, if any, should be discarded.

[image]

### Step 4 : Full code

crete new console app and cheange "Server=.;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;"

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static   void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;;Connection Timeout=0");
            connection.Open();
            var SPID = GetSPID(connection);
            var task1 = new Task(() => doLongSql(connection),
               TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            task1.Start();



            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10);//wait 10 seconds

            if (!task1.IsCompleted)
            {

               KillSPID( SPID);

            }

            Task.WaitAll(task1);

        }
        static int GetSPID(SqlConnection connection)
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select @@SPID ",connection);
            int SPID = Convert.ToInt32( command.ExecuteScalar()) ;
            return SPID;
        }

        static void KillSPID( int SPID)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"KILL {SPID}", connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }

        static void doLongSql(SqlConnection connection)
        {

            using (connection)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                  "WAITFOR DELAY '01:00'", //wait 1 minute
                  connection);
                 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
        }


    }
}
```

Ref:

- [Session ID of ADO.NET connection](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/94692d7b-69c6-4c34-a1dd-495c652e7d9d/session-id-of-adonet-connection?forum=sqldataaccess)
- [sql session_id c# - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?ei=7to1XNKdE4ryap-dsOAE&q=sql+session_id+c%23&oq=sql+session_id+c%23&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i7i30l2.1639.2559..2702...0.0..0.270.619.0j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.vEBDsHQHNww)
- [KILL (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/kill-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-with-statusonly)
- [isq sql KILL bad - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?ei=KOg1XKDHC4aT1fAP89WfuAo&q=isq+sql+KILL++bad&oq=isq+sql+KILL++bad&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3724.11130..11250...0.0..0.287.2707.0j10j4......0....1j2..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j0i30j0i13i30j35i39j0i131j0j0i67j0i10j0i13j0i13i10j0i13i10i30j0i8i13i10i30j33i160.SVMsutdpJeo)
- [Terminate, Stop, or Kill Long Running SQL Server Query - Discussion Forums - National Instruments](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Program-Drafts/Terminate-Stop-or-Kill-Long-Running-SQL-Server-Query/ta-p/3493642)
- [Options for Killing All Connections for a Database](https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/theres-more-one-way-kill-database-connection)
- [BREAK (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/break-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [sql server - Sleep Command in T-SQL? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664902/sleep-command-in-t-sql)
- [c# execute command in new thread async - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?ei=4d01XPaVGIe6a8Wbm6gN&q=c%23+execute+command+in+new+thread+async&oq=c%23+execute+command+in+new+thread+as&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.33i21j33i160.1524.1878..2800...0.0..0.238.623.0j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i22i30j33i22i29i30.cP81qoayUCM)
- [c# - Executing I command asynchronously - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48005520/executing-i-command-asynchronously)
- [Should I use Tasks for long running processes?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7f0ee464-37b3-47bb-abfe-77f61a5936af/should-i-use-tasks-for-long-running-processes?forum=csharpgeneral)
- [c# - Running multiple async tasks and waiting for them all to complete - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete)
- [c# - Connection timeout for SQL server - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308417/connection-timeout-for-sql-server)
- [How to: Cancel a Task and Its Children | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children)
- [[MS-TDS]: Attention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd341449.aspx)
- [Attention events can cause open transactions and blocking in SQL Server – Pankaj Mittal
- [MSFT]](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pamitt/2010/11/07/attention-events-can-cause-open-transactions-and-blocking-in-sql-server/)
- [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader)
- [SQL Server connection strings - ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

## Extra

```
SELECT conn.session_id, host_name, program_name,
    nt_domain, login_name, connect_time, last_request_end_time 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS sess
JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS conn
   ON sess.session_id = conn.session_id;
```

---

[image]

```
Select @@SPID
```

---

```
 KILL 56;
```

---

Comment: Thanks for reply. If you go through my code in post, I am processing my task in three parts. 1: `Jquery Ajax` call, 2: `c#` code which have some business logic. 3: Fetching data from `Sql`. I am not getting how your code fit to my scenario. And is it really required to `WAITFOR DELAY '01:00'`?