# Async in Program.cs

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an asp.net core api and I am seeding data in my database, however I am using the usermanager from identity core which requires async.

I tried to async the `void Main(string[] args)` but that did not work.

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {

               var dbContext = services.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();

                var userManager = services.GetService<UserManager<Employee>>();
                DbSeeder.CreateDefaultCompany(dbContext, userManager);

            }

            host.Run();
        }
```

The only way I figured out how to get around this(though, from what I read it might not be best practice is)

// inside CreateDefaultCompany

```
 userManager.CreateAsync(employee1, "parts").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: You should be able to declare Main as `static async Task Main(string[] args)` as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212343/7034621

Comment: I did try that originally but I get: Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Comment: @chobo2 did you change it to Task as well?

Comment: Make sure you set the project properties to ensure you are using at least C# v7.1 to get async main methods.

Comment: You can use `async Task Main()` if you are using c# 7.1 and Visual Studio 15.3+, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44254451/1260204) in the marked duplicate. If you are not able to use this version then see any of the other answers in the marked duplicate.