# Use of Async and await in console Application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have four methods.

1. Main: only calls the preform method
2. Working: displays "please wait for the user"
3. Taking Time: A program that takes time to execute.
4. Preform: Calls the taking time and working methods asynchronously.

The following is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncObservation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            preform();
        }
        public static async Task Working()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please wait, the program is running");  
        }
        public static async Task Takingtime()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This Program started");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("The Program finished"); 
        }
        public static async void preform()
        {
            Task timer = Takingtime();
            Task wait = Working();
        }
    }
}
```

---

In the end: I need to display

```
This program started. 
Please wait, the program is running 
The program ended.
```

Comment: what's the question here? avoid `async void`

Answer (score 7):

I see several problems in your program.

- Although `Preform` is neither async nor an event handler, it does not return a Task
- The tasks started in `Preform` are not awaited for before you finish Preform. Hence you never know when they are finished, nor what the results are (exception?). You could even end your program before they are finished
- After you start a Task it is not guaranteed when it will run. You can only be sure that statements are already executed if  you await for the Task.
- Using async-await is a method to make sure that your thread looks around to see if it can do useful stuff instead of waiting idly if it has to wait for something. `Thread.Sleep` is a busy wait. If you want to look around to see if you can do something else use `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))` instead.

In your case,  you can't be sure that any Console line has been written until you await the procedure that should write your line. If you start your second Task before awaiting the first, you don't know how far the first task already proceeded, and thus you don't know for sure that the text already has been written to the Console.

[C# 7.1 introduced async Task Main()](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-async-main-in-c-sharp-7-1/), so you could use that instead of the traditional `void Main`. It saves you from catching and interpreting the `AggregateException` that is thrown by the Task you start to make your process async.

If you don't want to use the `async Main`, you can of course use `Task.Run` to call an async function:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var preformTask = Task.Run( () => Preform() );

        DoSomethingElse();    // if needed
        preformTask.Wait();   // wait for preformTask to finish

        Console.WriteLine("Task completed; press any key to finish");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch (Exception exc) // inclusive ggregateException if one of your Task fails
    {
        ProcessException(exc)
    }
}

static async Task preform()
{
    // To be certain that the Console Line has been written: await
    await Takingtime();

    // if here, you are certain that the Line has been written,
    // or course you have lost parallel processing
    await Working();
}
```

For completeness: the other functions

```
public static async Task Working()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please wait, the program is running");

    // either return a completed Task, or await for it (there is a difference!
    await Task.CompletedTask;
    // or:
    return Task.CompletedTask; // do not declare async in this case
}

public static async Task Takingtime()
{
    Console.WriteLine("This Program started");

    //Use Task.Delay instead of Sleep
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);   // improved readability
    Console.WriteLine("The Program finished");
}
```

Because of the awaits in `Preform` you are certain that the text has been written. However, you've lost some parallellism.

If you really want those procedures to execute at the same time, you can't be certain about when text will be written. If that is important, then split the Parts that should be run first (write Console) from the parts that should run in parallel (Task.Delay)

```
static async Task preform()
{
    // Do the things that should be done before parallel tasks are run
    await DoThisFirst();

    // start the Tasks that can work parallel: not sure what statements are executed first
    var taskA = DoTaskA();
    var taskB = DoTaskB();

    // if here, you are free to do something else
    // can't be sure about the status of taskA nor taskB
    DoSomethingElse();

    // if you want to do something after you know that the tasks have completed:
    // await the tasks here:
    await Task.When (new Task[] {taskA, taskB});

    // if here, you are certain that all parallel tasks have completed successfully
    // if desired fetch the return values of the Tasks:
    var returnValueA = taskA.Result;
    var returnValueB = taskB.Result;

    // do all async things of which you needed to be certain that both tasks finished
    // for example:
    await ProcessResults(returnValueA, returnValueB);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a console app it is OK to use a `.Wait()` call in an `void Main` method.

In some contexts where there is synchronisation necessary `.Wait()` can cause deadlocks (ASP.NET has a request to synchronise on or XAML/WinForms which have a UI thread), but there is nothing to synchronise on here.

```
static void Main() 
{
     preform.Wait()
}
```

This will wait for the async work to complete synchronously. You need the method to run synchronously so that it does not return early. If you use `async void` and `await` the method will return immediately and exit the method, `await` does not work in a `Main` method.

I would also suggest using `await Task.Delay(1000);` rather than `Thread.Sleep(1000);` as this is the canonical `async` way to idle.

For your code example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        preform().Wait();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static async Task Working()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please wait, the program is running");
    }

    public static async Task Takingtime()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This Program started");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("The Program finished");
    }

    public static Task preform()
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(
            Takingtime(),
            Working());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with a full working example using my suggestions :)

Comment: You can try this [answear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212343/2343336) about async/await and asynchronous console programs

Comment: `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `.Wait()` unwraps the exception, if one is thrown.

Comment: @PauloMorgado, not quite. It will throw the first exception it encounters, it might hide exceptions thrown in other tasks that are still waiting to be checked. `Wait()` will throw an `AggregateException` that includes all exceptions thrown during the tasks passed to `WhenAll()`. Using the above code, add exceptions to both tasks called, there is a slight difference.

Comment: That's the behavior of `async-await` and the question was tagged `async-await`. And it's the behavior of [async `Main`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main).

Answer (score 2):

Use Stephen Cleary's Nito.AsyncEx library (available via Nuget) to provide an asynchronous context for a console application. See [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html) for more details.

Your application can then be written as ...

```
class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The application has started");
            AsyncContext.Run(() => LongRunningTaskAsync(args));
            Console.WriteLine("The application has finished");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    static async Task LongRunningTaskAsync(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The long running task has started");
        // use Task.Delay() rather than Thread.Sleep() to avoid blocking the application
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine("The long running task has finished");  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `preform().Wait()` in the constructor. So the call is awaited. Then use await `Takingtime()` and `await Working()` in the preform method.
And you have to change the return type to `Task`.

Comment: `async void` means it *can't* be awaited. That's why `async void` shouldn't be used

Comment: Oh yes you have to use Task as return type of the async methods

Comment: I have added that to the answer