# ML.NET to predict New York taxi fares - Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, ml.net

I was trying to do the example of ML.net to predict New York taxi fares, but when I finished the tutorial had the message: ***Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point***

Here the code that I did:

Class Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;
using Microsoft.ML.Models;
using Microsoft.ML.Trainers;
using Microsoft.ML.Transforms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaxiFarePrediction2
{
    public class Program
    {
        static readonly string _datapath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Data", "taxi-fare-train.csv");
        static readonly string _testdatapath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Data", "taxi-fare-test.csv");
        static readonly string _modelpath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Data", "Model.zip");


        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            PredictionModel<TaxiTrip, TaxiTripFarePrediction> model = await Train();
            Evaluate(model);
            TaxiTripFarePrediction prediction = model.Predict(TestTrips.Trip1);
            Console.WriteLine("Predicted fare: {0}, actual fare: 29.5", prediction.FareAmount);
        }


        public static async Task<PredictionModel<TaxiTrip, TaxiTripFarePrediction>> Train()
        {
            var pipeline = new LearningPipeline
            {
                new TextLoader(_datapath).CreateFrom<TaxiTrip>(useHeader: true, separator: ','),
                new ColumnCopier(("FareAmount", "Label")),
                new CategoricalOneHotVectorizer(
                    "VendorId",
                    "RateCode",
                    "PaymentType"),
                new ColumnConcatenator(
                    "Features",
                    "VendorId",
                    "RateCode",
                    "PassengerCount",
                    "TripDistance",
                    "PaymentType"),
                new FastTreeRegressor()
            };
            PredictionModel<TaxiTrip, TaxiTripFarePrediction> model = pipeline.Train<TaxiTrip, TaxiTripFarePrediction>();
            await model.WriteAsync(_modelpath);
            return model;
        }

        private static void Evaluate(PredictionModel<TaxiTrip, TaxiTripFarePrediction> model)
        {
            var testData = new TextLoader(_testdatapath).CreateFrom<TaxiTrip>(useHeader: true, separator: ',');
            var evaluator = new RegressionEvaluator();
            RegressionMetrics metrics = evaluator.Evaluate(model, testData);
            Console.WriteLine($"Rms = {metrics.Rms}");
            Console.WriteLine($"RSquared = {metrics.RSquared}");
        }


    }
}
```

class TaxiTrip.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Api;

namespace TaxiFarePrediction2
{
    public class TaxiTrip
    {
        [Column("0")]
        public string VendorId;

        [Column("1")]
        public string RateCode;

        [Column("2")]
        public float PassengerCount;

        [Column("3")]
        public float TripTime;

        [Column("4")]
        public float TripDistance;

        [Column("5")]
        public string PaymentType;

        [Column("6")]
        public float FareAmount;
    }

    public class TaxiTripFarePrediction
    {
        [ColumnName("Score")]
        public float FareAmount;
    }
}
```

class TestTrips.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Api;

namespace TaxiFarePrediction2
{
    public class TaxiTrip
    {
        [Column("0")]
        public string VendorId;

        [Column("1")]
        public string RateCode;

        [Column("2")]
        public float PassengerCount;

        [Column("3")]
        public float TripTime;

        [Column("4")]
        public float TripDistance;

        [Column("5")]
        public string PaymentType;

        [Column("6")]
        public float FareAmount;
    }

    public class TaxiTripFarePrediction
    {
        [ColumnName("Score")]
        public float FareAmount;
    }
}
```

The tutorial is in : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/taxi-fare

please help me to do this example.

Comment: IIRC "async Task" with main method is supported only after C# 7.  Which version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main method can not support asycn before c# 7.1, You can start main once and than create tasks in main method that can be async if you are using earlier versions.

You can writesomething mentioned by [Chris Moschini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24601591/6400526)

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // Do any async anything you need here without worry
    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

The link you posted clearly mention about c# version specified ...

> Because the async Main method is the feature added in C# 7.1 and the default language version of the project is C# 7.0, you need to change the language vers
>   ion to C# 7.1 or higher. To do that, right-click the project node in Solution Explorer and select Properties. Select the Build tab and select the Advanced button. In the dropdown, select C# 7.1 (or a higher version). Select the OK button.

[A good read on main with async](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/)

Comment: Don't know if that is the case but the code you pasted seems exactly like in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24601591/6400526. If that is the case then this is very discouraged on SO. A better way is to write your own code or just give the credit. Something like: "As written in this answer (link) you can do this: (code)"

Comment: Much better :) now it is a good answer

Comment: thanks for your help! It works well now :)

Comment: @johnnyLuis26 welcome !!! If this will help you in solving your issue, please accept it as the answer.