# "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point" when adding async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, system.net

So I have been fiddling around with Web responses and requests in C# and I received a problem when I tried to run the program. One of the lines of code I had:

```
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

required async in the method making

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
```

into

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
```

It looks like there is no error, but on build, I got the error message:

> Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.

Here is my code

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                /*HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://billing.roblox.com/v1/gamecard/redeem");
                            request.Method = "POST";
                            request.ContentType = "application/json";
                            request.Accept = "application/json";
                            JsonExtensionDataAttribute data = new JsonExtensionDataAttribute();
                            data = '3335996838'*/
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://billing.roblox.com/v1/gamecard/redeem"))
                    {
                        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");

                        request.Content = new StringContent("3335996838", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                        Console.WriteLine(request.Content);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                string content;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(content);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

Someone please help me!

Comment: Remove `Task`, add back `void`. But, you can take the suggestions you find here: [Can't specify the 'async' modifier on the 'Main' method of a console app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9208921/7444103). You'll have other problems after. The connection has a good chance to be closed before you can get a response.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you are still using Visual Studio 2017, since `async Main` [works out of the box for new projects on Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#csharp-defaults).

To allow `async Task Main`, you need to specify `LatestMinor` as your language version. (Build -> Advanced -> Language Version). `async Main` is a C# 7.1 language feature, and under VS2017, new projects default to C# 7.0.

Comment: Thank you, I have a question, how can I convert System.Net.Http.HttpContent to System.IO.Stream, kind of a out of the blue question but I cannot find a good answer online to help me with this issue.

Here is my current code
```
var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
                        using (var content1 = new StreamReader(response.Content))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(content1);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }```

Comment: I recommend asking a separate question since the new one really has nothing to do with this question. Keeping separate questions separate helps attract other answerers and helps future Googlers.

Comment: Excellent. That was exactly it! had to set Language version to C# 7.1 in Visual Studio 2017 and viola, works like a champ. Thank you !!

Answer (score -1):

It's required void return type for the main method.
You can back to void main and change this line:

```
  var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

to

```
var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

.Result is getting the result value of the task.