# Can the Main entry-point function be async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entry-point

I'm using .NET Framework, and I'm wanting to call an awaitable function in my `Main` entry-point function.

I'm using the `async` keyword on the function, but it keeps giving me [`CS5001`](https://bingdev.cloudapp.net/BingUrl.svc/Get?selectedText=Program%20does%20not%20contain%20a%20static%20%27Main%27%20method%20suitable%20for%20an%20entry%20point&mainLanguage=C%23&errorCode=CS5001) *Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point*. Although it doesn't say anything about it not being `async`.

It seems this error is related to the problem.

Comment: Have a read through the answer on the duplicate question there are some really handy ones which explain how to achieve what you are after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async Main methods were introduced with C#7.1, so if you are targeting that or above, you can use it.

Comment: You can't set `async` modifier on the Main method of a console app which is what the error in OPs question refers to.

Comment: @Adriani6 actually you can - starting with C# 7.1 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2017/12/08/async-main-is-available-but-hidden/

Comment: @Adriani6 In 7.1 you should be able to.

Comment: Did not know that! Thanks! +1 and apologies your way Lukas!

Comment: @Adriani6 Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44254451/2265446)