# Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException', Bad Request while bulk importing JSON to Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to bulk import a `JSON` file containing list of `JSONs` to Azure Cosmos DB from .Net 4.6.1 console application.

I'm successfully able to create the database and the container.
However I'm getting the following error at Line 40 and the items aren't getting created.
Error :

> DocDBTrace Error: 0 : Operation will NOT be retried. Current attempt 0, Status Code: BadRequest Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException' in Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.dll

Sample Code :

```
class Program
{

private static string EndpointUrl = $"";
private const string AuthorizationKey = "";
private const string DatabaseName = "TestDB";
private const string ContainerName = "BulkImportTest";
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText(@"BulkImport.json");

    List<StudentInfo> lists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StudentInfo>>(json);

    CosmosClientOptions options = new CosmosClientOptions() { ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway, AllowBulkExecution = true };
    CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUrl, AuthorizationKey, options);

    try
    {
        Database database = await cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(DatabaseName);
        Console.WriteLine(database.Id);
        Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(ContainerName, "/SId");
        Console.WriteLine(container.Id);
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (StudentInfo item in lists)
        {
                tasks.Add(container.CreateItemAsync(item, new PartitionKey(item.SId)));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // Line 40
        }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception = " + ex.Message);
    }


    Console.ReadLine();
}
    class StudentInfo
    {
        public string SId { get; set; }
        public string SName { get; set; }
    }}
```

BulkImport.json :

```
  [
  {
    "SId": "101",
    "SName": "ABC",
  },
  {
    "SId": "102",
    "SName": "XYZ",
  }
  ]
```

Please help me regarding this.

After making the suggested updates I'm still facing similar issue :

> DocDBTrace Error: 0 : Operation will NOT be retried. Current attempt 0, Status Code: BadRequest 
>   Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException' in Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException' in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Are you using cosmos db local emulator ?

Comment: No, I'm using it live

Comment: According to your json file and code, you use ```SID``` as PartitionKey. So please update your code ```database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(ContainerName, "/funcId");```to ```database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(ContainerName, "/SID");```. Besides, the formate of your json is wrong, it should be like ```[{"SID":"101","SName":"ABC"},{"SID":"102","SName":"XYZ"}]```

Comment: @JimXu Still giving the same error. Updated the code for all the changes made.

Comment: @aarohi-001 You need to delete the Container and run the new code.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Yeah I tried that but actually as given in Jim's answer I was missing the 'id' key from `json` data. Thank you for the quick responses. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my test, when we create a new document, we must provide "id" property. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/databases-containers-items#properties-of-an-item).

For example

My `.json` file

```
 [{
         "SId": "101",
         "SName": "ABC"
     }, {
         "SId": "102",
         "SName": "XYZ"
     }
 ]
```

My code

```
        async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\test.json");
            List<StudentInfo> lists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StudentInfo>>(json);            
            CosmosClientOptions options = new CosmosClientOptions() { AllowBulkExecution = true, ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway };
            CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUrl, AuthorizationKey, options);
            Database database = await cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(DatabaseName);
            Console.WriteLine(database.Id);
            Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(ContainerName,"/SId");
            Console.WriteLine(container.Id);
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (StudentInfo item in lists)
            {
                item.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();// add the line in your code
                tasks.Add(container.CreateItemAsync(item, new PartitionKey(item.SId))
                    .ContinueWith((Task<ItemResponse<StudentInfo>> task) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Status: " + task.Result.StatusCode + "    Resource: " + task.Result.Resource.SId);
                    }));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        class StudentInfo
        {            
            public string SId { get; set; }
            public string SName { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]// add the code in your custom object
            public string Id { get; set; }//add the code in your custom object

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this 'id' thing worked. But, I saw this in the document - "By default, all items that you add to a container are automatically indexed without requiring explicit index or schema management.", then why is id asked in jsons?

Answer (score 1):

Your documents do not contain the partition key.

Either make the Partition Key Path in the container match to some of your attributes (for example `/SID`), or make sure your JSON data contains documents with the `funcId` attribute.

```
[
  {
    "SID": "101",
    "SName": "ABC",
    "funcId" : "Something"
  }
  {
    "SID": "102",
    "SName": "XYZ",,
    "funcId" : "Something"
  }
  ]
```

Then load your documents with:

```
foreach (StudentInfo item in lists)
{
        tasks.Add(container.CreateItemAsync(item, new PartitionKey(item.funcId)));
}
```

With a model:

```
class StudentInfo
{
    public string SId { get; set; }
    public string funcId { get; set; }
    public string SName { get; set; }
}
```

OR, drop the Container and create it like so:

```
Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(ContainerName, "/SID");
```

Comment: Still giving the same error. Updated the code for all the changes made.

Comment: DId you delete the container before running the new code? The code calls `CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync` so if the container existed before with the wrong Partition Key path, it won't replace it.

Comment: I ran the fixed code in a new account and it worked correctly.