# Error while exporting from Azure Cosmos DB to Json file using Data Migration Tool

Tags: azure, export, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using the Microsoft Data migration tool to `import` from the Azure Cosmos Db `container` and `export` the content to a local `JSON` file.

I verified the connection string and it is successfully able to make connection with the database.

The query string is : `SELECT * FROM ContainerName;` Since I want all data.

However I'm facing the following error:

[image]

Edit:

The sample JSON that I'm trying to export:

[ {
    "id": "1",
    "SId": "101",
    "SName": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "SId": "102",
    "SName": "XYZ"
  }
]

I've imported this JSON to Cosmos DB using the
[code on this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991914/exception-thrown-microsoft-azure-cosmos-cosmosexception-bad-request-while-bu?noredirect=1#comment104322044_58991914)

Please help me regarding this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue on my side,so please refer to my working steps:

Source configuration:

[image]

Sink configuration:

[image]

Results in json file:

[image]

If you already pass through the verification of connection string,you could try to lock the issue in the error file.

[image]

---

Just for summary:

Finally, the issue is resulted from additional symbol `;` at the end of sql. Please remove it because it can't be identified by the tool.

Comment: I've edited my question with the json and code I used to import at first place.

Comment: @aarohi-001 I think the sample data is quite normal, are you make sure that the issue is not resulted from the connection string?

Comment: BTW, I do not have any option like Azure Cosmos DB for 'import from'. Instead I'm using Document DB for that.

Comment: No the connection string is verified.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203088/jay-and-aarohi ,would you please jump into this chat room?

Comment: Don't know why I'm not able to reply you there but I think I'm using the updated version only, still, I will check.

Comment: @aarohi-001 Maybe you don't have enough scores? Have no idea...

Comment: @aarohi-001 sure.

Comment: DISTINCT Keyword is not working in the migration tool query