# Cannot run ping inside task?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I want to make multiple ping using c#, but when i use ping class inside task the value of status not showing.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(()=> task());
    Console.WriteLine("FINISH");
   

}
public static  async Task task()
{       
    Ping pinger = null;
    pinger = new Ping();         
    var reply = pinger.Send("www.google.om", 1200);
    Console.WriteLine("TEST");
    bool pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    Console.WriteLine(pingable);
}
```

Comment: `await task();`

Comment: If you want to repeat something, you don't need a `Task`, you need a loop, like `while` or `for`.

Comment: The `task()` method has no asynchronous calls, so it will execute synchronously. Adding `async` won't make a method run asynchronously by itself. The way this method is written, it would be better to make it a `void task()`. Or a `bool task()` that returns the status

Comment: On the other hand, you could use [SendPingAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync?view=net-5.0) for truly asynchronous execution

Comment: The application closes immediately so how do you expect to see the results?

Comment: @jdweng try with console you will see. The apps will show just "FINISH" word. Becouse of that i ask here. My procedure run if without Task. You see on my description i want to create multiple ping. I expected is get value ping without waiting result the first ping (Like DUDE Apps for networking)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't specify the 'async' modifier on the 'Main' method of a console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app)

Answer (score 1):

Use [SendPingAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync?view=net-5.0) instead of `Send` inside another task:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using(var pinger = new Ping())
    {
        while(someCondition)
        {
            var reply=await pinger.SendPingAsync("www.google.om", 1200);
            var pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
            Console.WriteLine(pingable);
            //Wait for 1 second
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("FINISH");
}
```

Or

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using(var pinger = new Ping())
    {
        while(someCondition)
        {
            await ping(pinger);
            //Wait for 1 second
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("FINISH");
}

static async Task ping(Ping pinger)
{
    var reply=await pinger.SendPingAsync("www.google.om", 1200);
    var pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    Console.WriteLine(pingable);
}
```

The original code doesn't work because nothing awaits for the task started with `Task.Run` to complete, so the application terminates immediately. There's no need to use `Task.Run` though, because `Ping` has the asynchronous `SendPingAsync` class

Comment: Thanks you save my day.