# async Task or async void for Main method?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Should we use `async Task` or `async void` in the `Main` method of C# program?

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    //await something
}
```

or

```
public static async void Main(string[] args)
{
    //await something
}
```

I use `async Task` unless it is an event handler method as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). But I am always curious about whether those guidelines are still applied for the `Main` method (the entry point) of the program or are there any exceptions.

Comment: this should be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app

Comment: You should never be using `async void` unless you absolutely _have_ to anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [literally a compiler error](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAmARgFgAoaogZgAJSGBhagb2oe6bKSYAcTFAwCyAQwCWeABREyABgDaAXQbioAcwDOASi49OVHid4BOGQCJAPBuAQfcu6A3Ae4Bfaq6A=) for an `async Main` to be `void`:

```
error CS4009: A void or int returning entry point cannot be async
```

The fire-and-forget semantics of an `async void` make no sense for an entry point. The runtime has to get a `Task` to await or else it would never know when your application actually finished execution.