# C# .NET 7.0: How to convert top-level-statement program file to classic style?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've inherited a C# (.NET 7.0) project that includes program files written in the newer "top-level statement" style.  I need to change these to the classic C# program file style.  Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

The research I've done suggests that I can use ReSharper to do this.  But our company does not have a ReSharper license.  Thus, I need a way to accomplish this using only the built-in Visual Studio tools or by manually editing the project file.

Comment: why would you wanna switch back to old style ?

Comment: @J.Memisevic Suppose you want to initialize a `static readonly` field before your `Main()` logic runs.

Comment: Are there lots of these? Normally it's pretty straightforward to just wrap the whole code in `class Program { static void Main(string args[]) { ... } }` (adjusting for asynchrony and the return type), format the file, and you're done. You may then want to refactor the local functions to regular methods, but that can be done as and when you need it. Do you have so many of these that doing it manually isn't an option?

Comment: Visual Studio has a code fix for this. Put the cursor anywhere in the top-level statements and the lightbulb icon will show in the margin. If it's not too complicated to do automatically, the menu will include a "Convert to 'Program.Main' style program" item. It also has a code fix to go the other direction.

Comment: @madreflection Ooooh, I forgot about that. Now I'm embarrassed about my answer I posted...

Comment: @Dai: I don't believe the code fix is always possible, so your answer is always a viable approach. I do it that way myself, anyway, more or less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

1. Open your `Program.cs` file in VS.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>.
3. Type out `public static class Program{ public static async Task Main() {`
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>.
5. Type out `} }`.
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to re-format the file (to correct indenting, etc).
7. Save.

---

- No changes to your `.csproj` file should be necessary.
- Assuming you have the default settings still enabled, the act of pasting that C# code will automatically re-add the namespace-import `using` statements to the top of the file.
- This answer also assumes [you have *file scoped namespaces* enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/file-scoped-namespaces).

Comment: Why not a simple void Main() method instead of async? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212343/1728856